# Can I mask an input text in a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am writing a batch file to execute some other programs. In this case I need to prompt for a password. Do I have any way to mask the input text? I don't need to print ******* characters instead of input characters. Linux's Password prompt behavior (Print nothing while typing) is enough.

```
@echo off
SET /P variable=Password : 
echo %variable%
Pause
```

This will read the input but I can't mask the text using this approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the Windows batch equivalent for HTML's input type="password"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286871/what-would-be-the-windows-batch-equivalent-for-htmls-input-typepassword)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Up to XP and Server 2003, you can make use of another included tool (VBScript) - the following two scripts do the job you want.

First, `getpwd.cmd`:

```
@echo off
<nul: set /p passwd=Password: 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript /nologo getpwd.vbs') do set passwd=%%i
echo.
```

Then, `getpwd.vbs`:

```
Set oScriptPW = CreateObject("ScriptPW.Password")
strPassword = oScriptPW.GetPassword()
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine strPassword
```

The `getpwd.vbs` simply uses the password object to input the password from the user and then print it to standard output (the next paragraph will explain why that doesn't show up in the terminal).

The `getpwd.cmd` command script is a bit trickier but it basically works as follows.

The effect of the `"<nul: set /p passwd=Password: "` command is to output the prompt with no trailing newline character - it's a sneaky way to emulate the  `"echo -n"` command from the `bash` shell. It sets `passwd` to an empty string as an irrelevant side effect and doesn't wait for input since it's taking its input from the `nul:` device.

The `"for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript /nologo getpwd.vbs') do set passwd=%%i"` statement is the trickiest bit. It runs the VBScript with no Microsoft "advertising", so that the only line output is the password (from the VBscript `"Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine strPassword"`.

Setting the delimiters to nothing is required to capture an entire input line with spaces, otherwise you just get the first word. The `"for ... do set ..."` bit sets `passwd` to be the actual password output from the VBScript.

Then we echo a blank line (to terminate the `"Password: "` line) and the password will be in the `passwd` environment variable after the code has run.

---

Now, as mentioned, `scriptpw.dll` is available only up to XP/2003. In order to rectify this, you can simply copy the `scriptpw.dll` file from the `Windows\System32` folder of an XP/2003 system to the `Winnt\System32` or `Windows\System32` folder on your own system. Once the DLL has been copied, you will need to register it by running:

```
regsvr32 scriptpw.dll
```

To successfully register the DLL on Vista and later, you will need administrator privileges. I haven't examined the legality of such a move so cave lector.

---

If you're not *overly* keen on trying to track down and register older DLL files (for convenience or legal reasons), there is another way. Later versions of Windows (the ones that *don't* have the required DLL) should have Powershell available to you.

And, in fact, you really should consider upgrading your scripts to use it fully since it's a much more capable scripting language than `cmd.exe`. However, if you want to keep the bulk of your code as `cmd.exe` scripts (such as if you have a *lot* of code that you don't want to convert), you can use the same trick.

First, modify the `cmd` script so it calls Powershell rather than CScript:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('powershell -file getpwd.ps1') do set passwd=%%i
```

The Powershell script is equally simple:

```
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($password)
echo $password
```

although with some marshalling to get the actual password text.

Remember that, to run local unsigned Powershell scripts on your machine, you may need to modify the execution policy from the (draconian, though very safe) default, with something like:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

from within Powershell itself.

Comment: Whoa, that <nul: set /p is really cool. Didn't know that so far :-). But the VBScript doesn't work for me: Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'ScriptPW.Password'. Windows 7 Beta x64 here.

Comment: Interesting, it's supposed to be available from XP on. I'm suspecting Win7's not quite finished yet if it doesn't work there (or you have to do some other trickery to get it to work). A bit of research shows why: see my update.

Comment: Nice. It's also good to note you can substitute the VBS file for any equivalent language that can be called from the command line. For example, you can replace the cscript section with: 'python -c "from getpass import getpass; pwd = getpass(); print pwd;"'

Comment: I used to use this way back when this question was new - I answered [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file/20343074#20343074) a way to do it without extra scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is obsolete as `ScriptPW.Password` object only exists in Windows XP. Newer versions don't have it.

Comment: @Bill: Hence my section starting "Now, unfortunately, ..." :-) However, I've added more options to the answer to hopefully make it better. Specifically, the use of powershell rather than `scriptpw.dll`.

Answer (score 174):

Yes - I am 4 years late.

But I found a way to do this in one line without having to create an external script; by calling powershell commands from a batch file.

Thanks to TessellatingHeckler - without outputting to a text file (I set the powershell command in a variable, because it's pretty messy in one long line inside a for loop).

```
@echo off
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
echo %password%
```

Originally I wrote it to output to a text file, then read from that text file. But the above method is better. In one extremely long, near incomprehensible line:

```
@echo off
powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password" -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
echo %password%
```

I'll break this down - you can split it up over a few lines using caret `^`, which is much nicer...

```
@echo off
powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password" -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt 
set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
echo %password%
```

[This article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx) explains what the powershell commands are doing; essentially it gets input using `Read-Host -AsSecureString` - the following two lines convert that secure string back into plain text, the output (plaintext password) is then sent to a text file using `>.tmp.txt`. That file is then read into a variable and deleted.

Comment: This is brilliant. But the way it saves a plain text password to disk makes me uncomfortable. Avoid doing that by doing this instead: `for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%p in (``powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)"``) do set password=%%p` and then `echo %password%`. NB. I can't get this comment to escape backticks properly - before "powershell", and before the end ")" are two backticks, but should be one backtick.

Comment: Is is possible to stop this method from echoing "*" (star) for each keypress? i.e. I don't want an observer to know how long the password is.

Comment: I'm not sure, and can't really check right now. It would definitely be achieved at the Powershell level of this script. I am sure there is some way in powershell to supress output.

Comment: An issue I encountered: a command running as the input to a `for` loop has a subtly altered security context. `%psCommand%` worked just fine, but inside the `for` loop it would produce `The system cann

Comment: What if Powershell is disabled in your computer. Yes, powershell is disabled in my computer, maybe because I'm adventurous and it may destroy my computer. Does this set-up works?

Comment: @RegieBaguio No, you will need Powershell enabled. Take a look at npocmaka's pure Batch solution below. It's a lot more complicated, but should work for you.

Comment: So I'm using enabledelayedexpansion in my batch file. The problem is when my password has an exclamation mark in it it doesn't take unless I remember to escape it with the caret. Any thoughts?

Comment: As is, I was not able to use that solution directly. Told me that "[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)" was unexpected. this ended up working:

  powershell -Command "& {$pword = read-host `"Enter database password" -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) }"> .tmp.txt 
    set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt

Answer (score 26):

**1.Pure batch solution** that (ab)uses `XCOPY` command and its `/P /L` switches found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/f7mb_f99lYI) (some improvements on this could [be found here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4664&start=15) ):

```
:: Hidden.cmd
::Tom Lavedas, 02/05/2013, 02/20/2013
::Carlos, 02/22/2013
::https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/f7mb_f99lYI


@Echo Off
:HInput
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FILE=%Temp%.\T"
Set "FILE=.\T"
Keys List >"%File%"
Set /P "=Hidden text ending with Ctrl-C?: " <Nul
Echo.
Set "HInput="
:HInput_
For /F "tokens=1* delims=?" %%A In (
 '"Xcopy /P /L "%FILE%" "%FILE%" 2>Nul"'
) Do (
  Set "Text=%%B"
  If Defined Text (
    Set "Char=!Text:~1,1!"
    Set "Intro=1"
    For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%Z in ("!Char!") Do Set "Intro=0"
    Rem If press Intro
    If 1 Equ !Intro! Goto :HInput#
    Set "HInput=!HInput!!Char!"
  )
)
Goto :HInput_
:HInput#
Echo(!HInput!
Goto :Eof
```

**1.2 [Another way based on replace command](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6382)**

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set /P "=Enter a Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput
Echo(Your input was:!Line!

Goto :Eof

:PasswordInput
::Author: Carlos Montiers Aguilera
::Last updated: 20150401. Created: 20150401.
::Set in variable Line a input password
For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'"Echo(|Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W"') Do Set "CR=%%#"
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt $H &For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%#"
Set "Line="
:_PasswordInput_Kbd
Set "CHR=" & For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W') Do Set "CHR=%%#"
If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&Goto :Eof
If !CHR!==!BS! (If Defined Line (Set /P "=!BS! !BS!" <Nul
Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
)
) Else (Set /P "=*" <Nul
If !CHR!==! (Set "Line=!Line!^!"
) Else Set "Line=!Line!!CHR!"
)
Goto :_PasswordInput_Kbd
```

**2.Password submitter that uses a HTA pop-up**
. [This is a hybrit .bat/jscript/mshta](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543) file and should be saved as a [.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/ui.extensions/passwordSubmiter.bat):

```
<!-- :
:: PasswordSubmitter.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "pass=%%p"
)

echo your password is %pass%
exit /b
-->

<html>
<head><title>Password submitter</title></head>
<body>

    <script language='javascript' >
        window.resizeTo(300,150);
        function entperPressed(e){
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    pipePass();
                }
        }
        function pipePass() {
            var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value;
            var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(fso.Write(pass));

        }
    </script>

    <input type='password' name='pass' size='15' onkeypress="return entperPressed(event)" ></input>
    <hr>
    <button onclick='pipePass()'>Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**3.[A self-compiled .net hybrid](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5260)** .Again should be saved as [`.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/passHidder.bat) .In difference with other solutions it will create/compile a small .exe file that will be called (if you wish you can delete it). Also requires installed .net framework but that's rather not a problem:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('"%~n0.exe"') do (
    set "pass=%%p"
)

echo your password is !pass!

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/



import System;



var pwd = "";
var key;

Console.Error.Write("Enter password: ");

        do {
           key = Console.ReadKey(true);

           if ( (key.KeyChar.ToString().charCodeAt(0)) >= 20 && (key.KeyChar.ToString().charCodeAt(0) <= 126) ) {
              pwd=pwd+(key.KeyChar.ToString());
              Console.Error.Write("*");
           }

           if ( key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pwd.Length > 0 ) {
               pwd=pwd.Remove(pwd.Length-1);
               Console.Error.Write("\b \b");
           }


        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.Error.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(pwd);
```

Comment: My hacky sense is tingling, especially at the hybrid!

Comment: That first solution is very clever - nice one +1.

Comment: The 2.1 method based on the replace command will miss keypresses if you type quickly

Comment: @SamHasler - yes.I'll try to fix this.Though couldn't  reproduce the problem with the 2.1. I've also updated the HTA to check if enter is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for adding backspace handling to the third solution.

Comment: For those new to batch scripting, could you please provide a working example with a username and password prompt? Particularly with the xcopy version? Thank you.

Comment: @npocmaka the last version of the 1.2 method (Last updated: 20150405) is here: http://consolesoft.com/batch/password_input/password_input.cmd

Comment: @carlos - why just you don't add an answer with your tool and will delete it from my answer?

Comment: Wow, compiling jscript on the fly from a batch file. Now that's a party trick!

Comment: Amazing.  Love the mshta solution.

Answer (score 17):

I would probably just do:

```
..
echo Before you enter your password, make sure no-one is looking!
set /P password=Password:  
cls
echo Thanks, got that.
..
```

So you get a prompt, then the screen clears after it's entered.

Note that the entered password will be stored in the CMD history if the batch file is executed from a command prompt (Thanks [@Mark K Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file/665107?noredirect=1#comment38302913_665107)).

If that wasn't good enough, I would either switch to python, or write an executable instead of a script.

I know none of these are perfect soutions, but maybe one is good enough for you :)

Comment: Note that the entered password will be stored in the CMD history if the batch file is executed from a command prompt.  No downvote though as you did pretty much say that cmd is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: You can run `doskey /reinstall` to clear the previous command buffer immediately after `cls`, if the command history in the console is not important to you.

Comment: if you do not want to use doskey /reinstall and clear the command history, another option is run the above code in a separate terminal window and exit it immediately. Note that it still does not replace your typed String with asterisks. Above solution is an option if you do not want to run powershell. `C:\>start "console" cmd /c ireadconsole.bat`

Comment: Another option is to use something like:

`SET /P pw=C:\^>`

The ^ escapes the > so that the password prompt will look like a standard cmd console prompt.

Answer (score 16):

You may use ReadFormattedLine subroutine for all kind of formatted input. For example, the command below read a password of 8 characters, display asterisks in the screen, and continue automatically with no need to press Enter:

```
call :ReadFormattedLine password="********" /M "Enter password (8 chars): "
```

This subroutine is written in pure Batch so it does not require any additional program, and it allows several formatted input operations, like read just numbers, convert letters to uppercase, etc. You may download ReadFormattedLine subroutine from [Read a line with specific format](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5775).

---

**EDIT 2018-08-18**: *New method to enter an "invisible" password*

The FINDSTR command have a strange bug that happen when this command is used to show characters in color AND the output of such a command is redirected to CON device. For details on how use FINDSTR command to show text in color, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file#5344911).

When the output of this form of FINDSTR command is redirected to CON, something strange happens after the text is output in the desired color: all the text after it is output as "invisible" characters, although a more precise description is that the text is output as black text over black background. The original text will appear if you use COLOR command to reset the foreground and background colors of the entire screen. However, when the text is "invisible" we could execute a SET /P command, so all characters entered will not appear on the screen.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "=_" < NUL > "Enter password"
findstr /A:1E /V "^$" "Enter password" NUL > CON
del "Enter password"
set /P "password="
cls
color 07
echo The password read is: "%password%"
```

Answer (score 6):

another alternative is my EditV32 (x86) or EditV64 (x64) command-line tools. For example:

```
editv32 -m -p "Password: " PWD
```

-m means "masked input" and -p is the prompt. The user's input is stored in the PWD environment variable. You can get it here:

https://westmesatech.com/?page_id=19

Comment: This isn't the only closed-source solution (Windows is closed source!). You're free not to use it, of course...

Comment: If the lack of source code bothers you, see my other answer regarding [ReadLine.exe](http://www.westmesatech.com/misctools.html).

Comment: Good one! License allows you to use it. Moreover, easy to integrate. Just to handle the exit  code 1.  Error on the command line, 2  Input line was blank, 3  Environment variable was not changed, 4  Program aborted with Ctrl-C

Comment: Note: The editenv32/editenv64 and readline utilities have been superseded by the open-source [editenv](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv) utilty.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the forground color to black such:

```
:: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293220/what-is-the-fastest-color-function-in-batch
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"
set color_white=%ESC%[37m
set color_black=%ESC%[30m
echo(
set /p user=Username:
set /p pass=password:%color_black%
echo %color_white%
echo blablablba
```

Enjoy!!!
C.

Comment: just to note: works only as intended with `echo off`, else the `set` commands already change the color. And of course, when the background color is already black (it's by default, but you can't rely on it). Nice find (although I doubt it would have worked back in 2009)

Comment: I presume this works well against anyone looking over your shoulder, but not someone who can select/copy text out of the terminal afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Python installed, you can use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('python -c "import getpass; print(getpass.getpass('Enter the CVS password: '));"') do @set CVSPASS=%%A
echo PASS: %CVSPASS%
```

the output:

```
Enter the CVS password:
PASS: 123
```

Answer (score 4):

If the lack of source code bothers you, I have another alternative.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('ReadLine -h -p "Enter password: "') do set PWD=%%p
echo You entered: %PWD%
```

You can get it from https://westmesatech.com/?page_id=49. Source code is included.

Comment: Note: The editenv32/editenv64 and readline utilities have been superseded by the open-source [editenv](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv) utilty.

Answer (score 2):

I used Blorgbeard's above solution which is actually great in my opinion. Then I enhanced it as follows:

1. Google for **ansicon**
2. Download zip file and sample text file.
3. Install (that means copy 2 files into system32)

Use it like this:

```
@echo off
ansicon -p
set /p pwd=Password:ESC[0;37;47m
echo ESC[0m
```

This switches the console to gray on gray for your password entry and switches back when you are done. The ESC should actually be an unprintable character, which you can copy over from the downloaded sample text file (appears like a left-arrow in Notepad) into your batch file. You can use the sample text file to find the codes for all color combinations.

If you are not admin of the machine, you will probably be able to install the files in a non-system directory, then you have to append the directory to the PATH in your script before calling the program and using the escape sequences. This could even be the current directory probably, if you need a non-admin distributable package of just a few files.

Comment: I cant test this, but would  expect the typed password to appear in the cmd history afterwards.

Comment: @MarkKCowan That's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1):

make a batch file that calls the one needed for invisible characters then make a shortcut for the batch file being called.

right click

properties

colors

text==black

background == black

apply

ok

hope thus helps you!!!!!!!!

Comment: nice sideways thinking approach, even if not all always practical in a batch situation due to having to set the environment up ahead of time. Oh hang on, maybe this would work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14447306/14420 or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
I added two new methods that instead of utilizing cls to hide the input they create a new pop-up with one line only.

The drawbacks are that one method (method 2) leaves junk in the registry - "If run without proper rights", and the other one (method three) appends some junk to the script. Needless to say that it can easily be written to any tmp file and deleted I just tried to come up with an alternative.

**Limitation:** The password can only be alphanumeric - no other characters!

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="method%choice%" goto :method%choice%
::::::::::::::::::
::Your code here::
::::::::::::::::::
cls
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo ::::                   Batch script to prompt for password!                 :::
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:choice
echo.
echo 1. First method
echo.
echo 2. Second method
echo.
echo 3. Third method
echo.
set/p choice=Choose a method: 
if "%choice%" gtr "3" echo. & echo invalid option & echo. & pause & goto choice

call :vars
    set options= %num%%smAlph%%cpAlph%
    set pwdLen=6

if "%choice%" == "1" (
    set /p=Password: <nul 
    for /l %%i in (1,1,%pwdLen%) do call :password
) else (
    start /wait cmd /c call "%~f0" method%choice%
    )

call :result%choice%


::just to see if it worked!
echo.
echo The Password you entered is: "%pwd%"&pause>nul

::::::::::::::::::
::More code here::
::::::::::::::::::
exit /b





:vars
set num=1234567890
set smAlph=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set cpAlph=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    set pwd=
goto :EOF


:method2
call :popUp
setx result %pwd% >nul
goto :EOF

:method3
call :popUp
    >> "%~f0" echo.
    >> "%~f0" echo :result%choice%
    >> "%~f0" echo set pwd=%pwd%
goto :EOF

:popUp
title Password
mode con lines=1 cols=30
color 5a
set /p=Password: <nul
for /l %%i in (1,1,%pwdLen%) do call :password
goto :EOF

:password
:: If you don't want case sensative remove "/cs" but remember to remove %cpAlph% from the %options%
choice /c %options% /n /cs >nul
    call SET pwd=%pwd%%%options:~%errorlevel%,1%%
    set /p =*<nul
GOTO :EOF


:result2
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query hkcu\environment /v result') do set pwd=%%a
    setx result "" >nul
    reg delete hkcu\environment /v result /f >nul 2>&1
:result1
goto :EOF   
::You can delete from here whenever you want.
```

**Update:**
I found [sachadee's post to be perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893172/how-can-i-mask-input-by-using-batch-file-without-extra-file/) and I just added my "pop-up" quirk to it.

```
@Echo Off  
  SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  if "%1"==":HInput" goto :HInput
  set r=r%random%
  start /wait cmd /c call "%~f0" :HInput

For /f "tokens=2,13 delims=, " %%a in (
    'tasklist /v /fo csv /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"
    ^|findstr /v "Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
    ^|findstr "set /p=%r%"'
     ) do (
        set pid=%%a
        set Line=%%b
        set Line=!Line:%r%=!
        set Line=!Line:~,-2!
        )       
taskkill /pid %pid:"=%>nul
  goto :HIEnd


  :HInput
  SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  title Password
  mode con lines=2 cols=30

Echo Enter your Code :
   Set "Line="
   For /F %%# In (
   '"Prompt;$H&For %%# in (1) Do Rem"'
   ) Do Set "BS=%%#"

  :HILoop
   Set "Key="
   For /F "delims=" %%# In (
   'Xcopy /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
   ) Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%#"
   Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   If Not Defined Key start /min cmd /k mode con lines=1 cols=14 ^&set/p %r%!Line!=&exit
  If %BS%==^%Key% (Set /P "=%BS% %BS%" <Nul
   Set "Key="
   If Defined Line Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
   ) Else Set /P "=*" <Nul
   If Not Defined Line (EndLocal &Set "Line=%Key%"
   ) Else For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# In (
   "!Line!") Do EndLocal &Set "Line=%%#%Key%"
  Goto :HILoop

  :HIEnd
   Echo(
Echo Your code is :  "!Line!"
   Pause
   Goto :Eof
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an open source program called `editenv` that replaces my older `editv32`/`editv64` utilities:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv

The `--maskinput` (`-m`) option[*] lets you hide (mask) the typed input and has a configurable character (default character is `*`); e.g.:

```
editenv -m -p "Password: " PWD
```

The `--prompt` (`-p`) option lets you specify an input prompt. The above will display a `Password:` prompt and wait for you to enter something. Typed characters will appear as `*`. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will end the program with an exit code of 1223.

Download is here:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv/releases

[*] Note that the `--maskinput` (`-m`) option is **not secure** -- the entered string is entered as plain-text in the environment. This feature is for convenience only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just found a really decent work around to this issue. CMDKEY works on windows 7+ and allows you to enter details into the windows cred manager from the cmd prompt, and if you use the /pass switch it provides its own password entry without exposing the password. It does not present ***** as you type but the password is hidden.

The script below requests the username as normal and creates a var called "%username%" it then checks to see if the cred manager already has an entry for the target server. If it does it just maps the drive to the usename and does not request a password. If there is no entry it then uses the CMDKEY to prompt for password and stores it in cred manager.

```
    set /p username="Enter School Username: "
    CMDKEY /list:SERVERNAME | FIND "NONE" > nul 2>&1
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO MAPDRIVES
    CMDKEY /ADD:SERVERNAME /username:%username% /pass
    :MAPDRIVES
    NET USE Y: \\SERVERNAME\SHARE\%username%
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get [@unclemeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844742/unclemeat)'s answer to work on Windows 10 21H1 systems unfortunately. I just got: `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)"" was unexpected at this time.`

But he set me on the right track.

So here is my variant:

Configuration at top of script:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Don't leak variables to command shell
SETLOCAL

    REM service user for backend services - comment out to default to LOCALSYSTEM
SET WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME=svcadmin
```

Somewhere at the bottom after checking for admin privileges and after creating the service:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Read password for service user
IF DEFINED WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME (
    SET PWR=powershell -Command "$secureString = Read-Host 'Enter password for service user \".\%WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME%\"' -AsSecureString -ErrorAction Stop; $ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode($secureString); $plain = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($ptr); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode($ptr); Write-Host $plain;"
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%P IN (`!PWR!`) DO SET WINDOWS_SVC_PASSWORD=%%P
    IF DEFINED WINDOWS_SVC_PASSWORD (
        IF ["!WINDOWS_SVC_PASSWORD!"] NEQ [""] (
            IF ["!WINDOWS_SVC_PASSWORD!"] NEQ [" "] (
                :: The password is now set correctly
                ECHO "Using ".\%WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME%" as service user..."
                sc config  prod!WINDOWS_SVC_INFIX!rest!INDEX! obj= ".\!WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME!" password= "!WINDOWS_SVC_PASSWORD!"
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO "ERROR -- Password possibly empty or PowerShell threw an exception."
                SET "WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME="
            )
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO "ERROR -- Could not retrieve password! Password is possibly empty."
            SET "WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME="
        )
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO "ERROR -- No password given or PowerShell is not available."
        SET "WINDOWS_SVC_USERNAME="
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO "No service user specified - keeping default "LOCALSYSTEM" user..."
)
```

Of course the `sc config  prod!WINDOWS_SVC_INFIX!rest!INDEX!` is just copied from my for-loop further down and needs adaption to your specific case.
Use `ECHO password read: "!WINDOWS_SVC_PASSWORD!"` for debugging instead.

This is not yet tested in the wild, so please handle with care.

Answer (score 1):

Different answers to original question were already provided above, my preferred solution without storing password locally was based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file#comment34589774_20343074) from *TessellatingHeckler* above:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%p in (`powershell -Command "$pass = read-host 'Password' -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass); [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)"`) do set jira_password=%%p
```

However one point wasn't clearly addressed yet: don't forget to clear the password variable **before** retrieving it and **after** its usage (if you are not using the "setlocal" command), i.e. call the:

```
set "password="
```

Background: until the command session get closed - the variable stays stored and accessible also outside of your script. For example:

- run your batch script (which retrieves a password and shows it afterwards for test purpose)
- enter some text as a password and see it shown properly
- re-run same batch script without closing current command session
- don't enter anything (i.e. just press Enter when being asked for password)
- you will see the previously entered password.

Because some scripts being executed in a chain and you can't control the scripts executed in same session after your script - you should care on cleaning the user/password variables.

To avoid problems with unexpected exit from batch-script (i.e. when the variable clearing command being not reached), it's better to use

```
setlocal
...
endlocal
```

scopes.

Last but not least: if someone can [temporarily] modify your script - the given password could be stored somewhere or "forwarded" (i.e. get "lost").

Answer (score 0):

This may be an older topic, but if you are using Windows Vista or 7, I have a solution that will work very well. I made a video of it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk8uAa6PIFM

Pastebin for the batch file [is here](http://pastebin.com/WErALcGB)

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
color 0f
MODE CON COLS=132 LINES=50
:start
cls
choice /C ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!?.# /N /CS /M Please enter your password to continue. (Valid characters include all letters, numbers, and ! ? .) Press # to submit: 
SET ecode=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ecode% EQU 66 goto submit
IF %ecode% EQU 1 SET out=A
IF %ecode% EQU 2 SET out=B
IF %ecode% EQU 3 SET out=C
IF %ecode% EQU 4 SET out=D
IF %ecode% EQU 5 SET out=E
IF %ecode% EQU 6 SET out=F
IF %ecode% EQU 7 SET out=G
IF %ecode% EQU 8 SET out=H
IF %ecode% EQU 9 SET out=I
IF %ecode% EQU 10 SET out=J
IF %ecode% EQU 11 SET out=K
IF %ecode% EQU 12 SET out=L
IF %ecode% EQU 13 SET out=M
IF %ecode% EQU 14 SET out=N
IF %ecode% EQU 15 SET out=O
IF %ecode% EQU 16 SET out=P
IF %ecode% EQU 17 SET out=Q
IF %ecode% EQU 18 SET out=R
IF %ecode% EQU 19 SET out=S
IF %ecode% EQU 20 SET out=T
IF %ecode% EQU 21 SET out=U
IF %ecode% EQU 22 SET out=V
IF %ecode% EQU 23 SET out=W
IF %ecode% EQU 24 SET out=X
IF %ecode% EQU 25 SET out=Y
IF %ecode% EQU 26 SET out=Z
IF %ecode% EQU 27 SET out=a
IF %ecode% EQU 28 SET out=b
IF %ecode% EQU 29 SET out=c
IF %ecode% EQU 30 SET out=d
IF %ecode% EQU 31 SET out=e
IF %ecode% EQU 32 SET out=f
IF %ecode% EQU 33 SET out=g
IF %ecode% EQU 34 SET out=h
IF %ecode% EQU 35 SET out=i
IF %ecode% EQU 36 SET out=j
IF %ecode% EQU 37 SET out=k
IF %ecode% EQU 38 SET out=l
IF %ecode% EQU 39 SET out=m
IF %ecode% EQU 40 SET out=n
IF %ecode% EQU 41 SET out=o
IF %ecode% EQU 42 SET out=p
IF %ecode% EQU 43 SET out=q
IF %ecode% EQU 44 SET out=r
IF %ecode% EQU 45 SET out=s
IF %ecode% EQU 46 SET out=t
IF %ecode% EQU 47 SET out=u
IF %ecode% EQU 48 SET out=v
IF %ecode% EQU 49 SET out=w
IF %ecode% EQU 50 SET out=x
IF %ecode% EQU 51 SET out=y
IF %ecode% EQU 52 SET out=z
IF %ecode% EQU 53 SET out=0
IF %ecode% EQU 54 SET out=1
IF %ecode% EQU 55 SET out=2
IF %ecode% EQU 56 SET out=3
IF %ecode% EQU 57 SET out=4
IF %ecode% EQU 58 SET out=5
IF %ecode% EQU 59 SET out=6
IF %ecode% EQU 60 SET out=7
IF %ecode% EQU 61 SET out=8
IF %ecode% EQU 62 SET out=9
IF %ecode% EQU 63 SET out=!
IF %ecode% EQU 64 SET out=?
IF %ecode% EQU 65 SET out=.
SET code=%out%
SET show=*
:loop
cls
choice /C ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!?.# /N /CS /M Please enter your password to continue. (Valid characters include all letters, numbers, and ! ? .) Press # to submit: %code%
SET ecode=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ecode% EQU 66 goto submit
IF %ecode% EQU 1 SET out=A
IF %ecode% EQU 2 SET out=B
IF %ecode% EQU 3 SET out=C
IF %ecode% EQU 4 SET out=D
IF %ecode% EQU 5 SET out=E
IF %ecode% EQU 6 SET out=F
IF %ecode% EQU 7 SET out=G
IF %ecode% EQU 8 SET out=H
IF %ecode% EQU 9 SET out=I
IF %ecode% EQU 10 SET out=J
IF %ecode% EQU 11 SET out=K
IF %ecode% EQU 12 SET out=L
IF %ecode% EQU 13 SET out=M
IF %ecode% EQU 14 SET out=N
IF %ecode% EQU 15 SET out=O
IF %ecode% EQU 16 SET out=P
IF %ecode% EQU 17 SET out=Q
IF %ecode% EQU 18 SET out=R
IF %ecode% EQU 19 SET out=S
IF %ecode% EQU 20 SET out=T
IF %ecode% EQU 21 SET out=U
IF %ecode% EQU 22 SET out=V
IF %ecode% EQU 23 SET out=W
IF %ecode% EQU 24 SET out=X
IF %ecode% EQU 25 SET out=Y
IF %ecode% EQU 26 SET out=Z
IF %ecode% EQU 27 SET out=a
IF %ecode% EQU 28 SET out=b
IF %ecode% EQU 29 SET out=c
IF %ecode% EQU 30 SET out=d
IF %ecode% EQU 31 SET out=e
IF %ecode% EQU 32 SET out=f
IF %ecode% EQU 33 SET out=g
IF %ecode% EQU 34 SET out=h
IF %ecode% EQU 35 SET out=i
IF %ecode% EQU 36 SET out=j
IF %ecode% EQU 37 SET out=k
IF %ecode% EQU 38 SET out=l
IF %ecode% EQU 39 SET out=m
IF %ecode% EQU 40 SET out=n
IF %ecode% EQU 41 SET out=o
IF %ecode% EQU 42 SET out=p
IF %ecode% EQU 43 SET out=q
IF %ecode% EQU 44 SET out=r
IF %ecode% EQU 45 SET out=s
IF %ecode% EQU 46 SET out=t
IF %ecode% EQU 47 SET out=u
IF %ecode% EQU 48 SET out=v
IF %ecode% EQU 49 SET out=w
IF %ecode% EQU 50 SET out=x
IF %ecode% EQU 51 SET out=y
IF %ecode% EQU 52 SET out=z
IF %ecode% EQU 53 SET out=0
IF %ecode% EQU 54 SET out=1
IF %ecode% EQU 55 SET out=2
IF %ecode% EQU 56 SET out=3
IF %ecode% EQU 57 SET out=4
IF %ecode% EQU 58 SET out=5
IF %ecode% EQU 59 SET out=6
IF %ecode% EQU 60 SET out=7
IF %ecode% EQU 61 SET out=8
IF %ecode% EQU 62 SET out=9
IF %ecode% EQU 63 SET out=!
IF %ecode% EQU 64 SET out=?
IF %ecode% EQU 65 SET out=.
SET code=%code%%out%
SET show=%show%*
goto loop
:submit
cls
SET password=%code%
IF %password% EQU 0cZrocks! SET result=1
IF ELSE SET result=2
IF %result% EQU 1 echo password correct
IF %result% EQU 2 echo password incorrect
timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK >nul
cls
IF %result% EQU 1 goto end
IF ELSE goto start
:end
```

Comment: You didn't explained the code and you just copied that code. This is not a good way to do that, as you need to refresh the screen and the password needs to be x characters long.

Answer (score -4):

I read all the clunky solutions on the net about how to mask passwords in a batch file, the ones from using a hide.com solution and even the ones that make the text and the background the same color. The hide.com solution works decent, it isn't very secure, and it doesn't work in 64-bit Windows. So anyway, using 100% Microsoft utilities, there is a way!

First, let me explain my use. I have about 20 workstations that auto logon to Windows. They have one shortcut on their desktop - to a clinical application. The machines are locked down, they can't right click, they can't do anything but access the one shortcut on their desktop. Sometimes it is necessary for a technician to kick up some debug applications, browse windows explorer and look at log files without logging the autolog user account off.

So here is what I have done.

Do it however you wish, but I put my two batch files on a network share that the locked down computer has access to.

My solution utilizes 1 main component of Windows - runas.
Put a shortcut on the clients to the runas.bat you are about to create.
FYI, on my clients I renamed the shortcut for better viewing purposes and changed the icon.

You will need to create two batch files.

I named the batch files **runas.bat** and **Debug Support.bat**

**runas.bat contains the following code:**

```
cls
@echo off
TITLE CHECK CREDENTIALS 
goto menu

:menu
cls
echo.
echo           ....................................
echo            ~Written by Cajun Wonder 4/1/2010~
echo           ....................................
echo.
@set /p un=What is your domain username? 
if "%un%"=="PUT-YOUR-DOMAIN-USERNAME-HERE" goto debugsupport
if not "%un%"=="PUT-YOUR-DOMAIN-USERNAME-HERE" goto noaccess
echo.
:debugsupport
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\runas" /netonly /user:PUT-YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\%un% "\\PUT-YOUR-NETWORK-SHARE-PATH-HERE\Debug Support.bat"
@echo ACCESS GRANTED! LAUNCHING THE DEBUG UTILITIES....
@ping -n 4 127.0.0.1 > NUL
goto quit
:noaccess
cls
@echo.
@echo.
@echo.
@echo.
@echo   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
@echo   \\                                   \\
@echo   \\    Insufficient privileges         \\  
@echo   \\                                    \\
@echo   \\      Call Cajun Wonder             \\
@echo   \\                                    \\
@echo   \\              At                    \\
@echo   \\                                    \\
@echo   \\        555-555-5555                \\
@echo   \\                                    \\
@echo   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
@ping -n 4 127.0.0.1 > NUL
goto quit
@pause
:quit
@exit
```

You can add as many **if "%un%"** and if not "%un%" for all the users you want to give access to.
The @ping is my coonass way of making a seconds timer.

So that takes care of the first batch file - pretty simple eh?

Here is the code for Debug Support.bat:

```
cls
@echo off
TITLE SUPPORT UTILITIES
goto menu

:menu
cls
@echo %username%
echo.
echo           .....................................
echo            ~Written by Cajun Wonder 4/1/2010~
echo           .....................................
echo.
echo What do you want to do? 
echo.
echo [1]  Launch notepad
echo.

:choice
set /P C=[Option]? 
if "%C%"=="1" goto notepad
goto choice

:notepad
echo.
@echo starting notepad....
@ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL
start notepad
cls
goto menu
```

I'm not a coder and really just started getting into batch scripting about a year ago, and this round about way that I discovered of masking a password in a batch file is pretty awesome!

I hope to hear that someone other than me is able to get some use out of it!