# Getting input data after execution of batch file

Tags: batch-file, user-input, wifimanager

My batch file code is like this:

```
@echo off

C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe wlan set hostednetwor mode=allow ssid=User_Name key=password eyUsage=persistent
```

In this code the "User_name" and "password" fields I want the input from the user after running the batch file.
How do I make it ??? Please help.
And also suggest me modifications in this code if any.

Comment: Try `set /p` for more information type `set /?` on command-line.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help but Im not getting how to execute it in the code. Please tell me in detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Windows cmd, how do I prompt for user input and use the result in another command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
:Values
SET strSSID=
SET strPWD=
ECHO Please enter the ssid:
SET /p strSSID=SSID: 
ECHO.
ECHO Please enter the password:
SET /p strPWD=Password: 

IF ".%strSSID%"=="." GOTO :TryAgain
IF ".%strPWD%"=="." GOTO :TryAgain

CALL :HostedNW "%strSSID%" "%strPWD%"
GOTO :EOF

:HostedNW
ECHO NETSH WLAN SET hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="%~1" key="%~2" keyUsage=persistent
SET strSSID=
SET strPWD=
GOTO :EOF

:TryAgain
  CLS
  ECHO.
  ECHO One or more inputs weren't correct.
  ECHO Please try again.
  ECHO.
  GOTO :Values
```

I'm not familiar with netsh wlan hostednetwork. 
If there are always entered stings without spaces, the code could be simpler.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your valuable help. It Worked for me.