# Use BAT input later in script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I apologize if this is a) in the wrong section or b) a stupid question, but I've had little-to-no experience writing BAT files.
I'm trying to make a simple startup script for a game (specifically TF2). The way it runs is it takes a bunch of parameters in the startup, but the one I care about it the map. I want it to start with "What map do you want?", then wait for an input, then simply put that input in place of where a map would go in the startup. I haven't been able to find this simple answer online so far, so here I am. Here's the current script.

```
tf2\srcds.exe -console -game tf +sv_pure 1 +map MAP_HERE +maxplayers 24
```

How should I go about writing something like this?

Comment: The answer you seek lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SET`:

```
SET /P map=What map do you want?
tf2\srcds.exe -console -game tf +sv_pure 1 +map %map% +maxplayers 24
```

> `SET /P variable=[promptString]`
>
> The `/P` switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input entered by the user. Displays the specified `promptString` before reading the line of input.  The `promptString` can be empty.

See `cmd> set /?` for more on `SET`.