# .bat is there anyway I can use "pause" and not get the message Press any key to continue?"

Tags: batch-file

Does anybody know how to stop it coming up with that message thank you.
I have looked on the internet and cant find any answers.
Im making a basic RPG game using .bat and it ruins it by saying "Press any key to continue" if you guys know how to get rid of that message thankyou.

Comment: Does this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com] @echo off could be what you need also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the output of any command by adding `>nul` to the end.

In this case, use `pause >nul`

Comment: @XavierBall - happy to help. If my answer have you the solution you were looking for, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: can you please help me with my latest question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553934/bat-assistance-required-about-an-rpg-im-making thankyou : D

Answer (score 0):

```
pause >nul
```

but I guess you still need to press Enter key to continue.