# How can I accept arrow key presses from user input?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making an RPG style game and I've gotten to the point where I'm making the HUD. The ideal way it would run would be like this:

DPS: 18
Armour: 9
Open inventory
Open the Dungeon door

How can register arrow key presses to choose to either open the inventory or open the Dungeon door? Here is the code I have so far:

```
:HUD

set /p damage=DPS:

set /p armor= Armour:

set /p open=Open the Dungeon door! 

set /p inventory= Open Inventory!
```

Comment: Batch has no way of processing arrow key presses. Your options are to either use 2, 4, 6, and 8 to simulate arrow keys on the numpad, or to number the options and have the user enter a variable with either `set /p` or or `choice` if you aren't using Windows XP.

Comment: thx @SomethingDark your really helpful :D i dont think i can give u another tick tho :(

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because I don't consider "you can't" to be a decent answer.

Comment: sorry..... @SomethingDark

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand _the purpose_ of your question. Suppose you have a method to accept arrow key presses in a Batch variable, and further suppose that the user pressed an UpArrow and you get the appropriate value in the variable. What do you want to do after that? For example, if the Up/Down arrow keys were simulated via W/S letters keys, how this simulation could solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trick involving PowerShell to interpret arrow key presses in a batch script.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "=Hit an arrow key: "<NUL

:keyloop
call :getKey
if errorlevel 37 if not errorlevel 41 goto key%errorlevel%
goto keyloop

:key37
echo left
goto :EOF

:key38
echo up
goto :EOF

:key39
echo right
goto :EOF

:key40
echo down
goto :EOF

:getKey
powershell "exit($Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode)"
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

---

Upon reflecting on Klitos Kyriacou's comment below, it occurs to me that it'd be better to have PowerShell loop internally until the key code is a valid value.  Otherwise, a new instance of PowerShell would be spawned for each keypress, which would cause a delay if a bunch of invalid keys are pressed.  Here's a variation which addresses this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "getKeyMacro=powershell -noprofile "^
    while (-not (37..40).contains($x)) {^
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode^
    }^
    exit($x)^
""

set /P "=Hit an arrow key: "<NUL
%getKeyMacro%
if errorlevel 37 goto key%ERRORLEVEL%
rem // else user hit Ctrl-C.  Exit gracefully.
echo Bye. & goto :EOF

:key37
echo left
goto :EOF

:key38
echo up
goto :EOF

:key39
echo right
goto :EOF

:key40
echo down
goto :EOF
```

---

And here's an abbreviated version which has PowerShell convert the keycode to a human-readable string of left, up, right, or down.  It's perhaps not as useful for triggering conditional logic in a batch script, but do with it what you will.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "getKeyMacro=powershell -noprofile "^
    while (-not (37..40).contains($x)) {^
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode^
    }^
    ('left','up','right','down')[$x - 37]^
""

set /P "=Hit an arrow key: "<NUL
%getKeyMacro%
```

---

Just for fun, I wrote a menu selection script letting you make a selection using your arrow keys.  This also demonstrates a neat way to make a Batch + PowerShell hybrid chimera.

```js
<# : Batch portion
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "menu[0]=Format C:"
set "menu[1]=Send spam to boss"
set "menu[2]=Truncate database *"
set "menu[3]=Randomize user password"
set "menu[4]=Download Dilbert"
set "menu[5]=Hack local AD"

set "selection=0"
set "max=5"

:menu
cls
echo     === MENU ===
echo;
for /L %%I in (0,1,5) do (
    if %%I equ !selection! (
        echo --^> !menu[%%I]! ^<--
    ) else (
        echo     !menu[%%I]!
    )
)
echo;
echo Use the arrow keys and Enter to select.

powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy remotesigned "iex ((gc '%~f0') -join \";\")"
goto :key%errorlevel%

:key13 (enter)
echo You chose !menu[%selection%]!.
goto :EOF

:key39 (right)
:key40 (down)
if %selection% lss %max% set /a selection += 1
goto menu

:key37 (left)
:key38 (up)
if %selection% gtr 0 set /a selection -= 1
goto menu

: PowerShell hybrid chimera #>
while (-not ((37..40 + 13) -contains $x)) {
    $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
}
exit($x)
```

Here's another version that keeps the menu navigation within PowerShell.  An advantage to this is that `powershell` isn't respawned each time the menu selection is changed, so it'll run more responsively on slower computers.  Letting PowerShell output the menu also allows changing the background color of the selection.

```js
<# : Batch portion
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "menu[0]=Format C:"
set "menu[1]=Send spam to boss"
set "menu[2]=Truncate database *"
set "menu[3]=Randomize user password"
set "menu[4]=Download Dilbert"
set "menu[5]=Hack local AD"

set "default=0"

powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy remotesigned "iex ((gc '%~f0') -join \"`n\")"
echo You chose !menu[%ERRORLEVEL%]!.

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

$menu = gci env: | ?{ $_.Name -match "^menu\[\d+\]$" } | %{ $_.Value }
[int]$selection = $env:default
$fg = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
$bg = $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor

function getKey {
    while (-not ((37..40 + 13 + 48..53) -contains $x)) {
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
    }
    $x
}

function menu {
    cls
    write-host "   === MENU ===`n" -f $fg -b $bg

    for ($i=0; $item = $menu[$i]; $i++) {
        if ($i -eq $selection) {
            write-host "  > $item <  " -f $bg -b yellow
        } else {
            write-host " $i`: $item" -f $fg -b $bg
        }
    }

    write-host "`nChoose a number or use the arrow keys and Enter to select." -f $fg -b $bg
    1
}

while (menu) {

    [int]$key = getKey

    switch ($key) {

        37 {}   # left or up
        38 { if ($selection) { $selection-- }; break }

        39 {}   # right or down
        40 { if ($selection -lt ($menu.length - 1)) { $selection++ }; break }

        # number or enter
        default { if ($key -gt 13) {$selection = $key - 48}; [void](menu); exit($selection) }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use Powershell, then why not write the whole script in Powershell? It's a more powerful language than "Batch".

Comment: Because OP is looking for a turn key solution to plug into his existing batch script.  If you were 50% into developing a C# project and came here to ask how to perform a small task, would you find a suggestion to rewrite your project in Python very helpful?