# Batch: How can I request a User to input their name, then echo it?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a BATCH interface on notepad, and I want the user to input their name, before going to ECHO their name to the very next line. This is what I've done so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO ################################################
ECHO ## WELCOME TO THE BATCH INTERFACE, VERSION 1. ##
ECHO ################################################
ECHO ## PLEASE INPUT YOUR NAME TO CONTINUE:        ##
ECHO ################################################
PAUSE
```

Any luck?

Comment: read the output of `set /?`

Comment: If you would have Google searched `batch file user input`, this would have been the first link it would give you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET /p USERNAME=Enter Your Name:
ECHO %USERNAME%
```