# Simple batch for prompting hostname

Tags: windows, batch-file

At work I sometimes need to access any one of a number of network shares to view certain logs. The path is static `\\hostname\share_folder_name` but there are almost 50 servers setup like this which may need to be accessed.

Right now I have a basic batch written which will map the share for me, but currently it is specific only to the single host defined in the `.bat` file.

**Example:**

```
netuse A:\\\server1234\share_folder_name
```

I'd like to rewrite it so that it will prompt me to input ONLY the hostname each time as it's executed. *(That way I don't have to modify it 50 different times*).

Comment: `set /?` read about the `/p` switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Windows cmd, how do I prompt for user input and use the result in another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223721/in-windows-cmd-how-do-i-prompt-for-user-input-and-use-the-result-in-another-com)

Comment: another way is putting the hostname as a parameter to that batch file

Answer (score 0):

With Stephan's suggestion I was able to figure it out

```
    @echo off
    set /p Hostname="Enter Hostname:"
    echo %Hostname%
    net use * \\%Hostname%\Share_Folder /Persistent:No
```