# How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, colors

I know that the `color bf` command sets the colors of the whole command line window but I wanted to to print one single line in a different color.

Comment: It would seem that I there isn't any simple way of adding the escaped color codes to the Windows command line. :(

Comment: rui, if Win10 is an acceptable OS version, check out Jens's answer - it should be exactly what you need, seeing as this question never accepted an answer seven years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38617204/3543437

Comment: Same question on SuperUser: [Windows console with ANSI colors handling - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling)

Answer (score 426, accepted):

> I wanted to to print one single line in a different color.

Use ANSI Escape Sequences.

**Windows before Windows 10 - no native support for ANSI colors on the console**

For Windows version below 10, the Windows command console doesn't support output coloring by default. You could install either [Cmder](http://cmder.net/), [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) or [Mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) (used by default in GitBash and Cygwin) to add coloring support to your Windows command console.

**Windows 10 and later - Command Line Colors**

Starting from Windows 10 the Windows console support ANSI Escape Sequences and some colors by default. The feature shipped with the Threshold 2 Update in Nov 2015.

**[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx)**

**Update** (05-2019): The [ColorTool](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal/tree/master/src/tools/ColorTool) enables you to change the color scheme of the console. It's part of the Microsoft [Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/Terminal) project.

**Demo**

[image: colors in commandline]

**Batch Command**

The [`win10colors.cmd`](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011#file-win10colors-cmd) was written by [Michele Locati](https://github.com/mlocati):

️*The text below is stripped of special characters and will not work. You must copy it from [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd).*

```
@echo off
cls
echo [101;93m STYLES [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[0m [0mReset[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[1m [1mBold[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[4m [4mUnderline[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m [7mInverse[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m NORMAL FOREGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[30m [30mBlack[0m (black)
echo ^<ESC^>[31m [31mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[32m [32mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[33m [33mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[34m [34mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[35m [35mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[36m [36mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[37m [37mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m NORMAL BACKGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[40m [40mBlack[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[41m [41mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[42m [42mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[43m [43mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[44m [44mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[45m [45mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[46m [46mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[47m [47mWhite[0m (white)
echo.
echo [101;93m STRONG FOREGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[90m [90mWhite[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[91m [91mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[92m [92mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[93m [93mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[94m [94mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[95m [95mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[96m [96mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[97m [97mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m STRONG BACKGROUND COLORS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[100m [100mBlack[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[101m [101mRed[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[102m [102mGreen[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[103m [103mYellow[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[104m [104mBlue[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[105m [105mMagenta[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[106m [106mCyan[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[107m [107mWhite[0m
echo.
echo [101;93m COMBINATIONS [0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m                     [31mred foreground color[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m                      [7minverse foreground ^<-^> background[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7;31m                   [7;31minverse red foreground color[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m and nested ^<ESC^>[31m [7mbefore [31mnested[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m and nested ^<ESC^>[7m [31mbefore [7mnested[0m
```

Comment: @Jens A. Koch - it is not working in my windows 10 console ( cmd )

Comment: That's odd, but a local problem. 1) Make sure you have Windows 10 with the Threshold 2 update (Nov 2015). It's needed for color support. ( It's working. Just tested with Version 10.0.14393.) --- 2) You saved the content to a file `colors.cmd` and ran that, right?

Comment: @Jens A. Koch 1) I am using Windows 10 Pro, Version 1607, OS Build 14393.693 2) I have file .bat not .cmd - can I use .bat not .cmd ?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback. `.cmd` or `.bat` - both should work. But, i think i know why it doesn't work: it seems the escape symbol is removed when posting to StackOverflow. Please do not copy the content from my answer, use the content from here instead: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd

Comment: @Jens A. Koch yes, you are right - now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: I never had to generate a `ESC` in notepad++ before... You can do this with ALT-codes using the numpad and the left ALT key: `L-ALT`+`0`+`2`+`7`

Comment: Btw, as someone who makes and uses a lot batches most days, this answer has enhanced my overall toolset in an aesthetic way! Using VB? Hell no. This is _the_ way to go!

Comment: You can generate an `ESC` character in a Batch file this way: `for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"`

Comment: This seem to not work any more in newer versions of Windows 10... [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44047988/985454)

Comment: @Qwerty it still works in Creator's Update, but one of the updates seems to have caused a bug that can make triggering it more difficult if it is a consumed script. You might need to start using a shim or calling your scripts with an extra switch, depending on what shells you're planning on supporting with coloration. I ran into a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45449530/3543437

Comment: @JensA.Koch This is awesome. But I have a problem with it running in a for loop. Only the first echo gets properly colored, after that all other ones just print all escape characters instead of changing anything. Batch file is to archive each folder to separate archive, trying to ouput folder name in bold, followed by archiver standard output with findstr filtering.

Comment: **You can change the color without creating a new line: `echo | set /p="ESCAPECHARACTER[91m"`**

Comment: When executing my script (a `*.cmd` file), the escape sequences only work on the first `echo` statement. After this, the `esc` character is rendered with the unknown character symbol, along with the rest of the escape sequence and the sequence is not processed. @Aacini method to generate the escape works just as well as using Notepad++ and the key sequence of `Alt+0`, `Alt+2`, `Alt+7`. I am guessing there is a bug in the console window's terminal emulation.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Thanks for posting a Notepad++ workaround for inserting the ESC. It was a bit finickey for me, I think the NUM-lock state is important (but my Microsoft keyboard doesn't have an LED to show its state, so can't say which state worked!).

Comment: Works for the first echo in my for-loop but not subsequent iterations, where the escape characters are instead displayed as a special character, small P or ? in a rectangular box :(

Comment: @Zeek2 check this gist. You might need to manually replace the special characters using alt codes, and yes the numpad being enabled as well as using the numbers only from the numpad does matter: https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/fdccf686c5d017094fa76e805b2b05d6

Comment: @Aacini could you please explain how your command invocation works? I don't understand how the contents of the list evaluate to an escape character.

Comment: @RyanMcClue: I am afraid I don't understand what you are referring to... What "command invocation"? What "contents of the list"? Are you talking about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line/38617204?noredirect=1#comment74171363_38617204)?

Comment: @Aacini Yes I was talking about that comment. Don't worry though, I understand it now.

Comment: Hi Jens, may I update your question with an image that shows _all_ available color codes: https://imgur.com/a/EuNXEar and with the script that created it: https://gist.github.com/gerib/f2562474e7ca0d3cda600366ee4b8a45?

Answer (score 64):

This isn't a great answer, but if you know the target workstation has Powershell you can do something like this (assuming BAT / CMD script):

```
CALL:ECHORED "Print me in red!"

:ECHORED
%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe write-host -foregroundcolor Red %1
goto:eof
```

---

## Edit: <sub><sup>(now simpler!)</sup></sub>

It's an old answer but I figured I'd clarify & simplify a bit

[image: img]

[PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/powershell-scripting) is now [*included* in all versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell) of Windows since 7.  Therefore the syntax for this answer can be shortened to a simpler form:

- the **path** doesn't need to be specified since it should be in the environment variable already.
- **unambiguous** commands can be [abbreviated](https://serverfault.com/a/777619/438416). For example you can:

  - use `-fore` instead of `-foregroundcolor`
  - use `-back` instead of `-backgroundcolor`
- the command can also basically be used '**inline**' in place of `echo`
  (rather than creating a separate batch file as above).

---

### Example:

```
powershell write-host -fore Cyan This is Cyan text
powershell write-host -back Red This is Red background
```

---

### More Information:

The complete list of colors and more information is available in the
- **PowerShell [Documentation for `Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)**

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/11/powertip-write-powershell-output-in-color-without-using-write-host.aspx

Comment: Greate,it works for me,but it's tooooooooooooooo slow.

Comment: i realize that this is an answer providing a solution, but powershell? ugh.

Comment: That's why I started with "This isn't a great answer". I quite like Powershell but it's overkill for this. ANSICON is better if you can cope with deploying it to the target machines.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I've looked high and low for a way to echo colored output from a batch file in Powershell and this was the only one. Not sure why it takes so long to actually print it (there's like a 1 second wait with each call) but at least I can do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 57):

This is a self-compiled **bat/.net hybrid** (should be saved as `.BAT`) that can be used on any system that have installed .net framework  (it's a rare thing to see an windows without .NET framework even for the oldest XP/2003 installations) . It uses jscript.net compiler to create an exe capable to print strings with different background/foreground color only for the current line.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)

%~n0.exe %*

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

import System;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

var newLine = false;
var output = "";
var foregroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
var backgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
var evaluate = false;
var currentBackground=Console.BackgroundColor;
var currentForeground=Console.ForegroundColor;


//http://stackoverflow.com/a/24294348/388389
var jsEscapes = {
  'n': '\n',
  'r': '\r',
  't': '\t',
  'f': '\f',
  'v': '\v',
  'b': '\b'
};

function decodeJsEscape(_, hex0, hex1, octal, other) {
  var hex = hex0 || hex1;
  if (hex) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16)); }
  if (octal) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(octal, 8)); }
  return jsEscapes[other] || other;
}

function decodeJsString(s) {
  return s.replace(
      // Matches an escape sequence with UTF-16 in group 1, single byte hex in group 2,
      // octal in group 3, and arbitrary other single-character escapes in group 4.
      /\\(?:u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-3][0-7]{0,2}|[4-7][0-7]?)|(.))/g,
      decodeJsEscape);
}


function printHelp( ) {
   print( arguments[0] + "  -s string [-f foreground] [-b background] [-n] [-e]" );
   print( " " );
   print( " string          String to be printed" );
   print( " foreground      Foreground color - a " );
   print( "                 number between 0 and 15." );
   print( " background      Background color - a " );
   print( "                 number between 0 and 15." );
   print( " -n              Indicates if a new line should" );
   print( "                 be written at the end of the ");
   print( "                 string(by default - no)." );
   print( " -e              Evaluates special character " );
   print( "                 sequences like \\n\\b\\r and etc ");
   print( "" );
   print( "Colors :" );
   for ( var c = 0 ; c < 16 ; c++ ) {
        
        Console.BackgroundColor = c;
        Console.Write( " " );
        Console.BackgroundColor=currentBackground;
        Console.Write( "-"+c );
        Console.WriteLine( "" );
   }
   Console.BackgroundColor=currentBackground;
   
   

}

function errorChecker( e:Error ) {
        if ( e.message == "Input string was not in a correct format." ) {
            print( "the color parameters should be numbers between 0 and 15" );
            Environment.Exit( 1 );
        } else if (e.message == "Index was outside the bounds of the array.") {
            print( "invalid arguments" );
            Environment.Exit( 2 );
        } else {
            print ( "Error Message: " + e.message );
            print ( "Error Code: " + ( e.number & 0xFFFF ) );
            print ( "Error Name: " + e.name );
            Environment.Exit( 666 );
        }
}

function numberChecker( i:Int32 ){
    if( i > 15 || i < 0 ) {
        print("the color parameters should be numbers between 0 and 15");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}


if ( arguments.length == 1 || arguments[1].toLowerCase() == "-help" || arguments[1].toLowerCase() == "-help"   ) {
    printHelp();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

for (var arg = 1; arg <= arguments.length-1; arg++ ) {
    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-n" ) {
        newLine=true;
    }
    
    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-e" ) {
        evaluate=true;
    }
    
    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-s" ) {
        output=arguments[arg+1];
    }
    
    
    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-b" ) {
        
        try {
            backgroundColor=Int32.Parse( arguments[arg+1] );
        } catch(e) {
            errorChecker(e);
        }
    }
    
    if ( arguments[arg].toLowerCase() == "-f" ) {
        try {
            foregroundColor=Int32.Parse(arguments[arg+1]);
        } catch(e) {
            errorChecker(e);
        }
    }
}

Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor ;
Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor ;

if ( evaluate ) {
    output=decodeJsString(output);
}

if ( newLine ) {
    Console.WriteLine(output);  
} else {
    Console.Write(output);
    
}

Console.BackgroundColor = currentBackground;
Console.ForegroundColor = currentForeground;
```

Here's the help message:

[image]

**Example**:

`coloroutput.bat  -s "aa\nbb\n\u0025cc" -b 10 -f 3 -n -e`

You can also find this script [here](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/coloroutput.bat).

You can also check carlos' color function -> http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4453

Comment: How cool is that. A bat file that compiles the jscript that is in it and only if it needs to - I'm well impressed.  Didn't even know there was a jscript compiler just sitting there waiting to be used.  You get my "awesome award" for the month.  You ought to mention that the first use of it will be slow (because of the compile).

Comment: I don't need colour badly enough to go to this extreme, but the technique is really impressive and I can see myself using that elsewhere.

Answer (score 50):

**Windows 10 - TH2 and above:**

(a.k.a. Version 1511, build 10586, release 2015-11-10)

**At Command Prompt:**

```
echo ^[[32m HI ^[[0m
```

Using the actual keys:    echo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>`[32m HI`  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>`[0m`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You should see a green "HI" below it.

Code numbers can be found here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

**Notepad:**

To save this into notepad, you can type ESC into it using: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`027` with the numpad, then the `[32m` part.  Another trick when I was on a laptop, redirect the line above into a file to get started, then cut and paste:

```
echo echo ^[[32m HI ^[[0m >> batch_file.cmd
```

Comment: Alt + 027 was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Alt+027 dosn't work in Eclipse/Java .. also tried `\033` but nope ... how could I do this in Java?

Comment: on windows 10 and above, this works in DOS and Notepad++ editor. Thanks!

Comment: `Ctrl`+`[` was what I needed!Thank you.But how did you know the shotcut?I didn't find anything in MDN

Comment: @SmartCoder Traditionally `^[` sends the ASCII code for the ESC char.  Left bracket shares the same trailing 5 bits as ESC, Ctrl key clears the top 2.  This is why `^M` is an alias for Enter, for example.  Find an ASCII table in 4 columns of 32 to see the relationships easily.  I tried it on the console and it worked!

Comment: Another notepad tip, is once you've got it working in the command window (eg with the ctrl key), you can pipe it to the clip command (to your clipboard) then paste it into notepad/script

Eg (don't copy&paste this, you have to use the ctrl + [ key):        

`echo ^[[32m | clip`

Answer (score 21):

You can just creates files with the name of the word to print, uses findstr which can print in color, and then erases the file. Try this example:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

call :ColorText 0a "green"
call :ColorText 0C "red"
call :ColorText 0b "cyan"
echo(
call :ColorText 19 "blue"
call :ColorText 2F "white"
call :ColorText 4e "yellow"

goto :eof

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

Run `color /?` to get a list of colors.

Comment: This sets colors in windows command line. Could you explain what it does?

Comment: Ok, it just creates files with the name of the word to print, uses findstr which can print in color, and then erases the file.

Comment: That is impressive! Note that the colour codes are wrong. Run "color /?" to see the actual colour codes.

Comment: Note that findstr can only colourize the *filename*, which means you can't use this trick for strings that contain illegal path characters.

Comment: It can handle all characters you only need to modify the filename, [SO:How to have multiple colors in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/463115)

Comment: @jeb not all characters are legal filename characters (slashes, quotes, asterisk, and question mark for example).

Comment: Also of note, this will overwrite files in the same directory if they share the name of what you're trying to print... that's not good at all.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I know that not all characters are vaild, but they are allowed in the filename when they are in front of `\..\`. And I don't overwrite files, the only file I create is named `X`. This post is only the copy of my first solution, indeed that can overwrite existing files

Comment: My files was deleted because of this

Comment: Did you just take it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file/5344911#5344911? If so, you should probably mention it.

Comment: Yeah, as Stefans has already said, deletes files when you use it to echo out the filename. **DO NOT USE FOR FILENAMES**.

Answer (score 15):

You could use [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) to enable ANSI terminal codes in older versions of Windows.  There are 32 and 64 bit versions that I have used in Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: Can't get it to work on windows 8.1. Crashing everytime I try and install.

Comment: @EHerman Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070524/ansicon-doesnt-work-with-windows-8) will help.

Comment: ANSICON is not needed in later versions of Win 10.  Don't try to use it there.

Answer (score 7):

There is an accepted answer with more than 250 upvotes already. The reason I am still contributing is that the `escape` character required for echoing is not accepted by many editors (I am using, e.g., MS Code) and all other solutions require some third-party (non-Windows-default) pieces of software.

The work-around with using only plain batch commands is using `PROMPT` instead of `ECHO`. The `PROMPT` command accepts the `escape` character in an any-editor-friendly way as a `$E`character sequence. (Simply replace the `Esc` in the [ASCII Escape codes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)) with `$E`.

Here is a demo code:

```
@ECHO OFF

    :: Do not pollute environment with the %prompt.bak% variable
    :: ! forgetting ENDLOCAL at the end of the batch leads to prompt corruption
    SETLOCAL

    :: Old prompt settings backup
    SET prompt.bak=%PROMPT%

    :: Entering the "ECHO"-like section

        :: Forcing prompt to display after every command (see below)
        ECHO ON

        :: Setting the prompt using the ANSI Escape sequence(s)
        :: - Always start with $E[1A, otherwise the text would appear on a next line
        :: - Then the decorated text follows
        :: - And it all ends with $E30;40m, which makes the following command invisible
        ::   - assuming default background color of the screen
        @ PROMPT $E[1A$E[30;42mHELLO$E[30;40m

        :: An "empty" command that forces the prompt to display. 
        :: The word "rem" is displayed along with the prompt text but is made invisible
        rem

        :: Just another text to display
        @ PROMPT $E[1A$E[33;41mWORLD$E[30;40m
        rem

        :: Leaving the "ECHO"-like section
        @ECHO OFF

    :: Or a more readable version utilizing the cursor manipulation ASCII ESC sequences

        :: the initial sequence
        PROMPT $E[1A
        :: formating commands
        PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[32;44m
        :: the text
        PROMPT %PROMPT%This is an "ECHO"ed text...
        :: new line; 2000 is to move to the left "a lot"
        PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[1B$E[2000D
        :: formating commands fro the next line
        PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[33;47m
        :: the text (new line)
        PROMPT %PROMPT%...spreading over two lines
        :: the closing sequence
        PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[30;40m

        :: Looks like this without the intermediate comments:
        :: PROMPT $E[1A
        :: PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[32;44m
        :: PROMPT %PROMPT%This is an "ECHO"ed text...
        :: PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[1B$E[2000D
        :: PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[33;47m
        :: PROMPT %PROMPT%...spreading over two lines
        :: PROMPT %PROMPT%$E[30;40m

        :: show it all at once!
        ECHO ON
        rem
        @ECHO OFF

    :: End of "ECHO"-ing

    :: Setting prompt back to its original value
    :: - We prepend the settings with $E[37;40m in case
    ::   the original prompt settings do not specify color
    ::   (as they don't by default).
    :: - If they do, the $E[37;40m will become overridden, anyway.
    :: ! It is important to write this command 
    ::   as it is with `ENDLOCAL` and in the `&` form.
    ENDLOCAL & PROMPT $E[37;40m%prompt.bak%

EXIT /B 0
```

NOTE: The only drawback is that this technique collides with user cmd color settings (`color` command or settings) if not known explicitly.

-- Hope this helps as thi is the only solution acceptable for me for the reasons mentioned at the beginning. --

**EDIT:**

Based on comments, I am enclosing another snippet inspired by @Jeb. It:

- Shows how to obtain and use the "Esc" character runtime (rather than entering it to an editor) (Jeb's solution)
- Uses "native" `ECHO` command(s)
- So it does not affect local `PROMPT` value
- Demonstrates that coloring the `ECHO` output inevitably affect `PROMPT` color so the color must be reset, anyway

```
@ECHO OFF

    :: ! To observe color effects on prompt below in this script
    ::   run the script from a fresh cmd window with no custom
    ::   prompt settings

    :: Only not to pollute the environment with the %\e% variable (see below)
    :: Not needed because of the `PROMPT` variable
    SETLOCAL

        :: Parsing the `escape` character (ASCII 27) to a %\e% variable
        :: Use %\e% in place of `Esc` in the [http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php]
        FOR /F "delims=#" %%E IN ('"prompt #$E# & FOR %%E IN (1) DO rem"') DO SET "\e=%%E"

        :: Demonstrate that prompt did not get corrupted by the previous FOR
        ECHO ON
        rem : After for
        @ECHO OFF

        :: Some fancy ASCII ESC staff
        ECHO [          ]
        FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,10) DO (
            TIMEOUT /T 1 > NUL
            ECHO %\e%[1A%\e%[%%GC%\e%[31;43m.
            ECHO %\e%[1A%\e%[11C%\e%[37;40m]
        )

        :: ECHO another decorated text
        :: - notice the `%\e%[30C` cursor positioning sequence
        ::   for the sake of the "After ECHO" test below
        ECHO %\e%[1A%\e%[13C%\e%[32;47mHELLO WORLD%\e%[30C

        :: Demonstrate that prompt did not get corrupted by ECHOing
        :: neither does the cursor positioning take effect.
        :: ! But the color settings do.
        ECHO ON
        rem : After ECHO
        @ECHO OFF

    ENDLOCAL

    :: Demonstrate that color settings do not reset
    :: even when out of the SETLOCAL scope
    ECHO ON
    rem : After ENDLOCAL
    @ECHO OFF

    :: Reset the `PROMPT` color
    :: - `PROMPT` itself is untouched so we did not need to backup it.
    :: - Still ECHOING in color apparently collide with user color cmd settings (if any).
    :: ! Resetting `PROMPT` color this way extends the `PROMPT`
    ::   by the initial `$E[37;40m` sequence every time the script runs.
    :: - Better solution then would be to end every (or last) `ECHO` command
    ::   with the `%\e%[37;40m` sequence and avoid setting `PROMPT` altogether.
    ::   which makes this technique preferable to the previous one (before EDIT)
    :: - I am keeping it this way only to be able to
    ::   demonstrate the `ECHO` color effects on the `PROMPT` above.
    PROMPT $E[37;40m%PROMPT%

    ECHO ON
    rem : After PROMPT color reset
    @ECHO OFF

EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: @VonC You can simply create a variable, containing the escape chatacter, without the need to enter it into the editor. `for /F "delims=#" %%E in ('"prompt #$E# & for %%E in (1) do rem"') do set "\e=%%E"`

Comment: @jeb Do you mean "as opposed to `echo` used in [batcolors/echo.bat](https://github.com/VonC/batcolors/blob/83bcef4cf8b3d79b86cb5823d59fb3fa21ccd8c6/echos.bat#L18)"?

Comment: @VonC Yes, replace your `set ASCII27=←` with `for /F "delims=#" %%E in ('"prompt #$E# & for %%E in (1) do rem"') do set "ASCII27=%%E"`. This uses the escape character created by the prompt command, without changing the prompt permanently (because the `prompt` command is executed in a child process). Btw. Your `echos.bat` has some optimization potential ...

Comment: @jeb "Your echos.bat has some optimization potential": I am sure of it :) Pull Requests are welcome (both for the ASCII27 and other optimisations)

Comment: @jeb Thank you in advance. [`test_colors.bat`](https://github.com/VonC/batcolors/blob/83bcef4cf8b3d79b86cb5823d59fb3fa21ccd8c6/test_colors.bat) will allow you to check if everything is still working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206508/discussion-between-jeb-and-vonc).

Comment: 1) Wow, I would not expect this topic be so hot! :) My solution comes from the good old "no-for" days, still I like the trick of obtaining the ASCII27 character (I guess I would not reveal it myself) 2) It seems that the ECHO-ed version still inevitably changes prompt collor settings (even with SETLOCAL) so that resetting the prompt collor is needed at the end. (eddited my post)

Comment: @PavDub Thank you for your answer: here is the result, thanks to jeb's expertise: https://github.com/VonC/batcolors

Comment: @VonC: The method to create a variable with the ESC character appears in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line/38617204?noredirect=1#comment74171363_38617204) posted more than 3 years ago, and it uses a simpler method!

Comment: @Aacini That seems simpler than https://github.com/VonC/batcolors/blob/b19953fc7daf108fa632fefc0ead0afdeaff59ae/echo_macros.bat#L41-L43 indeed.

Answer (score 6):

I was annoyed by the lack of proper coloring in cmd too, so I went ahead and created **cmdcolor**. It's just an stdout proxy, which looks for a limited set of ANSI/VT100 control sequences (in other words, like in bash), i.e. `echo \033[31m RED \033[0m DEFAULT | cmdcolor.exe`.

[Usage and downloads](https://github.com/jeremejevs/cmdcolor).

Comment: This is cool, and I've put it into the menu system of a giant build script at my work.  Only beef I have is that the binary you provide on that page targets 64-bit, so it won't work on our 32-bit build machine.  But it was no problem just grabbing the source and compiling myself.

Comment: But it's 32-bit :) Here's the output of GNU file: `cmdcolor.exe; PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit`

Comment: That's odd...  XP Pro refused to run it, but it ran fine on my Win7 64 box.  I compiled with Visual C++, targeting Win32, and it was fine.

Comment: Huh... probably because of `upx`. Could you contact me via e-mail, please?

Answer (score 6):

I looked at this because I wanted to introduce some simple text colors to a Win7 Batch file. This is what I came up with.  Thanks for your help.

```
@echo off
cls && color 08

rem .... the following line creates a [DEL] [ASCII 8] [Backspace] character to use later
rem .... All this to remove [:]
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")

echo.

<nul set /p="("
call :PainText 09 "BLUE is cold"    && <nul set /p=")  ("
call :PainText 02 "GREEN is earth"  && <nul set /p=")  ("
call :PainText F0 "BLACK is night"  && <nul set /p=")"
echo.
<nul set /p="("
call :PainText 04 "RED is blood"    && <nul set /p=")  ("
call :PainText 0e "YELLOW is pee"   && <nul set /p=")  ("
call :PainText 0F "WHITE all colors"&& <nul set /p=")"

goto :end

:PainText
<nul set /p "=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "+" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul
goto :eof

:end
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding an answer to address an issue noted in some comments above: that inline ansi color codes can misbehave when inside a FOR loop (actually, within any parenthesized block of code).  **The .bat code below demonstrates (1) the use of inline color codes, (2) the color failure that can occur when inline color codes are used in a FOR loop or within a parenthesized block of code, and (3) a solution to the problem.**  When the .bat code executes, tests 2 and 3 demonstrate the colorcode failure, and test 4 shows no failure because it implements the solution.

[EDIT 2020-04-07: I found another solution that's presumably more efficient than calling a subroutine. Enclose the FINDSTR phrase in parentheses, as in the following line:

```
   echo success | (findstr /R success)
```

ENDEDIT]

Note: In my (limited) experience, the color code problem manifests only after input is piped to FINDSTR inside the block of code.  That's how the following .bat reproduces the problem.  **It's possible the color code problem is more general than after piping to FINDSTR.  If someone can explain the nature of the problem, and if there's a better way to solve it, I'd appreciate it.**

```
@goto :main
:resetANSI
EXIT /B
rem  The resetANSI subroutine is used to fix the colorcode
rem  bug, even though it appears to do nothing.

:main
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem  Define some useful colorcode vars:
for /F "delims=#" %%E in ('"prompt #$E# & for %%E in (1) do rem"') do set "ESCchar=%%E"
set "green=%ESCchar%[92m"
set "yellow=%ESCchar%[93m"
set "magenta=%ESCchar%[95m"
set "cyan=%ESCchar%[96m"
set "white=%ESCchar%[97m"
set "black=%ESCchar%[30m"

echo %white%Test 1 is NOT in a FOR loop nor within parentheses, and color works right.
   echo %yellow%[Test 1] %green%This is Green, %magenta%this is Magenta, and %yellow%this is Yellow.
   echo %Next, the string 'success' will be piped to FINDSTR...
   echo success | findstr /R success
   echo %magenta%This is magenta and FINDSTR found and displayed 'success'.%yellow%
   echo %green%This is green.
echo %cyan%Test 1 completed.

echo %white%Test 2 is within parentheses, and color stops working after the pipe to FINDSTR.
(  echo %yellow%[Test 2] %green%This is Green, %magenta%this is Magenta, and %yellow%this is Yellow.
   echo %Next, the string 'success' will be piped to FINDSTR...
   echo success | findstr /R success
   echo %magenta%This is supposed to be magenta and FINDSTR found and displayed 'success'.
   echo %green%This is supposed to be green.
)
echo %cyan%Test 2 completed.

echo %white%Test 3 is within a FOR loop, and color stops working after the pipe to FINDSTR.
for /L %%G in (3,1,3) do (
   echo %yellow%[Test %%G] %green%This is Green, %magenta%this is Magenta, and %yellow%this is Yellow.
   echo %Next, the string 'success' will be piped to FINDSTR...
   echo success | findstr /R success
   echo %magenta%This is supposed to be magenta and FINDSTR found and displayed 'success'.
   echo %green%This is supposed to be green.
)
echo %cyan%Test 3 completed.

echo %white%Test 4 is in a FOR loop but color works right because subroutine :resetANSI is 
echo called after the pipe to FINDSTR, before the next color code is used.
for /L %%G in (4,1,4) do (
   echo %yellow%[Test %%G] %green%This is Green, %magenta%this is Magenta, and %yellow%this is Yellow.
   echo %Next, the string 'success' will be piped to FINDSTR...
   echo success | findstr /R success
   call :resetANSI
   echo %magenta%This is magenta and FINDSTR found and displayed 'success'.
   echo %green%This is green.
)
echo %cyan%Test 4 completed.%white%

EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: This is just help, as optical example, when make or modify colorful command prompt echoes.]

The following code consists of two parts. If it is convenient for you too, there is also a .txt format in this .cmd file, below the "double" line (====).

```
::adonios77
::This is a .cmd file
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Colored Command Prompt echoes HELP
mode con: cols=55 lines=47
CLS
COLOR 0f 
echo [93m
ECHO This is just help, as optical example,
ECHO when make or modify colorful command prompt echoes.
ECHO.
ECHO More info in Source:
ECHO [4m[94mhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line[0m

ECHO.
ECHO [0mESC[0m "Text" Default colours Text[0m
ECHO [7mESC[7m "Text" Inversed Back-Fore colors[0m 
ECHO [101mESC[101m "Text" in Red Background[0m
ECHO [91mESC[91m "Text" in Red Foreground)[0m

echo.
echo To make an ESC special character, (ASCII Escape code)
echo open or edit a .txt or .bat or .cmd file,
echo (hold)L-Alt and (type)027 in NumPad)
echo Or, in Command Prompt, (can't copy/paste special char.)
echo just press Ctrl+[ 
echo  (it should look like: "echo ^[[33m'Text'^[[0m")
echo. 
echo STYLES
echo [0mESC[0m Reset[0m
echo [1mESC[1m Bold [90m*This is not work for me[0m
echo [4mESC[4m Underline[0m
echo [7mESC[7m[0m Inverse
echo. 
echo COLORS#  Foreground-Background (color /? HEX) && echo.
echo           [90mDark[0m     /    [100mLight[0m
echo        Fore-Back   /  Fore-Back
echo Black  *   [100m[30m30[0m-[4m[40m40  [0m   (0) / (8) [90m90[0m-[100m100 [0m
echo Red        [31m31[0m-[41m41  [0m   (4) / (C) [91m91[0m-[101m101 [0m
echo Green      [32m32[0m-[42m42  [0m   (2) / (A) [92m92[0m-[102m102 [0m
echo Yellow         [33m33[0m-[90m[43m43  [0m   (6) / (E) [93m93[0m-[90m[103m103 [0m
echo Blue       [34m34[0m-[44m44  [0m   (1) / (9) [94m94[0m-[104m104 [0m
echo Magenta    [35m35[0m-[45m45  [0m   (5) / (D) [95m95[0m-[105m105 [0m
echo Cyan       [36m36[0m-[46m46  [0m   (3) / (B) [96m96[0m-[106m106 [0m
echo White  *   [37m37[0m-[47m47  [0m   (7) / (F) [97m97[0m-[7;97m107 [0m
echo. 
echo Note: use ESC[0m at the end of (every) line.
echo. 
echo COMBINATIONS
echo [7;91mESC[7;91m inverse red foreground color ESC[0m[0m
echo. 

ECHO. && PAUSE
exit

============================================================
:: This is a .txt file.
 This is just help, as optical example,
 when make or modify colorful command prompt echoes.

 More info in Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line

To make an ESC special character, (),
open or edit a .txt or .bat or .cmd file,
(hold)L-Alt and (type)027 in NumPad)

STYLES
[0m Reset
[1m Bold
[4m Underline
[7m Inverse

COLORS#  (Foreground-Background)
            Dark        /     Light
        Fore-Back       /   Fore-Back
Black       30-40   (0) / (8)   90-100
Red         31-41   (4) / (C)   91-101
Green       32-42   (2) / (A)   92-102
Yellow      33-43   (6) / (E)   93-103
Blue        34-44   (1) / (9)   94-104
Magenta     35-45   (5) / (D)   95-105
Cyan        36-46   (3) / (B)   96-106
White       37-47   (7) / (F)   97-107

COMBINATIONS
ESC[7;31m inverse red foreground color 0m

Note: use ESC[0m at the end of (every) line.

examples:
@ECHO OFF
ECHO          Default Text
ECHO [7m"Text" Inversed Back-Fore colors (7m)[0m 
ECHO [101m"Text" in Red Background (101m)[0m
ECHO [91m"Text" in Red Foreground (91m)[0m

============================================================
```

Also, I figured out that with this way can be change the way the Command Prompt looks like, temporarily or permanently.
The following TEXT code is an example of:

[image: SET_PROMPT_Colored.PNG]

> ```
> This is a .txt file.
>
>  Antony's examples:
>
> prompt $Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$S $T$_ $P\$_$G 
>  gives something like that:
>
> ====================  19:53:02,73
>  C:\Windows\system32\
> > 
>
> For All Users & Permanent: 
> (if there is space between characters, must double quoted [""])
> SETX /M PROMPT  $Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$S$S$T$_$_$S$P\$_$G$S
>  gives something like that:
>
> ====================   9:01:23,17
>
>  C:\Windows\system32\
> > 
>
> NOTE: Variables created or modified by SETX
>          will be available at the next logon session.
> ```

Now let's give colors to the above examples. ***The result in the image above.***

COLORED PROMPT examples:

For only the current User:

```
PROMPT $E[91m$E[40m$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$S $T$E[93m$_ $P\$_$G$E[0m
```

or

For All Users and Permanently:

```
SETX /M PROMPT $E[91m$E[40m$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$Q$S$S$T$E[93m$_$_$S$P\$_$G$S$E[0m
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! To colorize *the path* in the CMD prompt. I used `prompt $E^[[96m$P$G $E^[[0m` where `^[` was typed using <kbd>ctrl+[</kbd> keys. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: And I have updated your command with moving the `SETX /M` param before the command to be stored. Note for others: I did not added the escape Ctrl+[ character that be followed after each `$E` , i.e. `$E^[`

Answer (score 3):

An option for non windows 10 users that doesn't require calling labels, avoiding the delays that go with doing so.

Below is a macro verison of a findstr colorprint routine

usage - where BF is replaced with the hex digit values of the background / Foreground colors:
%Col%{BF}{"string to print"}

```bat
@Echo off & CD "%TEMP%"
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
 Set "Col=For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (Set "_Str="&(For /F "tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%G in ("!oline!")Do Set "C_Out=%%G" & Set "_Str=%%~H")&(For %%s in (!_Str!)Do Set ".Str=%%s")&( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "!_Str!" )&( findstr /v /a:!C_Out! /R "^$" "!_Str!" nul )&( del " !_Str!" > nul 2>&1 ))Else Set Oline="
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* concatenation of multiple macro expansions requires the macro to be expanded within it's own code block. */
 (%Col%{02}{"green on black,"}) & (%Col%{10}{black on blue})
 Echo/& (%Col%{04}{red on black}) & (%Col%{34}{" red on blue"})
Goto :Eof
```

A more robust version of the macro replete with error handling.

```bat
@Echo off & PUSHD "%TEMP%"
rem /* Macro Definitions */
(Set  \n=^^^
%= macro newline Do not modify =%
)
(Set LF=^


%= linefeed. Do not modify =%)
 If "!![" == "[" (
  Echo/%%COL%% macro must be defined prior to delayed expansion being enabled
  Goto :end
 )
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
rem /* %hCol% - Alternate color macro; escaped for use in COL macro. No error checking. Usage: (%hCol:?=HEXVALUE%Output String) */
 Set "hCol=For %%o in (1 2)Do if %%o==2 (^<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" ^> "!os!" ^& findstr /v /a:? /R "^$" "!os!" nul ^& del "!os!" ^> nul 2^>^&1 )Else Set os="
rem /* %TB%   - used with substitution within COL macro to format help output; not fit for general use, */
 Set "TB=^&^< nul Set /P "=.%DEL%!TAB!"^&"
rem /* %COL%  - main color output macro. Usage: (%COL%{[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]}{String to Print}) */
 Set COL=Set "_v=1"^&Set "Oline="^& For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (%\n%
  If not "!Oline!" == "" (%\n%
   Set "_Str="%\n%
   For /F "tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%G in ("!oline!")Do (%\n%
    Set "Hex=%%G"%\n%
    Set "_Str=%%~H"%\n%
   )%\n%
   Echo/!Hex!^|findstr /RX "[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]" ^> nul ^|^| (Echo/^&(%hCol:?=04%Invalid - )%TB%(%hCol:?=06%Bad Hex value.)%TB%(%hCol:?=01%%%COL%%{!Hex!}{!_Str!})%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=02%!Usage!)^&Set "_Str="^&Set "_v=0")%\n%
   If not "!_Str!" == "" (%\n%
    ^<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" ^> "!_Str!"%\n%
    findstr /v /a:!Hex! /R "^$" "!_Str!" nul %\n%
    del "!_Str!" ^> nul 2^>^&1%\n%
   )Else If not !_v! EQU 0 (%\n%
    Echo/^&(%hCol:?=04%Invalid -)%TB%(%hCol:?=06%Arg 2 absent.)%TB%(%hCol:?=01%%%COL%%!Oline!)%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=04%Input is required for output string.)%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=02%!Usage!)%\n%
   )%\n%
  )Else (Echo/^&(%hCol:?=04%Invalid -)%TB%(%hCol:?=06%No Args)%TB:TAB=!TAB!!TAB!%(%hCol:?=01%%%COL%%!Oline!)%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=02%!Usage!))%\n%
 )Else Set Oline=
 Set "usage=%%COL%%{[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]}{String to Print}"
 For /F eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do Set "TAB=%%A"
rem /* removes escaping from macros to enable use outside of COL macro */
 Set "hCol=%hCol:^=%"
 Set "TB=%TB:^=%"
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 rem /* usage examples */
 (%COL%{02}{"green on black,"}) & (%COL%{10}{"black on blue"})
 Echo/
 (%COL%{04}{"red on black"}) & (%COL%{34}{" red on blue"})&(%COL%{40}{"black on red"})
 Echo/& %COL%{03}{Demonstration of error handling-}
rem /* error handling */
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=20%Example 1 - No args
%COL%
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=20%Example 2 - Missing 2nd Arg
%COL%{ff}
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=20%Example 3 - Invalid hex value for 1st Arg
%COL%{HF}{string}
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=0d%Done
:end
POPD
Goto :Eof
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An advanced Macro for handling Cursor Color, Position and properties For Windows 10.
Please refer to the help and usage examples for information on usage.

**Supports and Shows examples of:**

- Cursor Positioning

  - Absolute
  - Relative to last Cursor Position ; left right by n columns ; up down by n lines
  - Combinations of Relative and Absolute Position.
- Show / Hide Cursor
- Cursor Graphics properties [ Color ; Foreground and Background ]

  - Same line multicolor output
  - Easily chain multiple VT graphics sequences.
- Clearing of all text on a line from a given position.
- Deletion of a number of characters to the right of the cursor on the current line.
- Optionally Save the Cursor position at the time of expansion as independent Y and X values.

  - **/Save** Cursor position storing component of the macro adpated from [Jeb's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38240300/12343998)
- **NEW:** Switching between Screen buffers.

> **Edit:**
>
> I've included below the final usage example a command line that uses
> VT codes to achieve the same result as that example, to illustrate the
> difference in readability when using multiple Terminal sequences in
> the same Cursor output.
>
> **NOTES On changing Buffers:**
>
> Cursor position is tied to the active buffer; It is not availale when switching to an alternate buffer.
> When reverting to the main buffer:
> The cursor position originally occupied in the main buffer is restored, and the content of the alternate buffer is discarded.

```bat
::: Cout cursor Macro. Author: T3RRY ::: Filename: Cout.bat
::: OS requirement: Windows 10
::: Purpose: Facilitate advanced console display output with the easy use of Virtual terminal codes
::: Uses a macro function to effect display without users needing to memorise or learn specific
::: virtual terminal sequences.
::: Enables output of text in 255 bit color at absolute or relative Y;X positions.
::: Allows cursor to be hidden or shown during and after text output. See help for more info.

@Echo off & Setlocal EnableExtensions
============================================== :# Usage
 If not "%~1" == "" Echo/%~1.|findstr /LIC:"/?" > nul && (
  If "%~2" == "" (Cls &  Mode 1000,50 & Color 30)
  If "%~2" == "Usage" ( Color 04 & ( Echo/n|choice /n /C:o 2> nul ) & timeout /T 5 > nul )
  If "%~2" == "DE" ( Color 04 & Echo/                      --- Delayed expansion detected^^^! Must not be enabled prior to calling %~n0 ---&( Echo/n|choice /n /C:o 2> nul ))
  If not Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0helpfile.~tmp" (For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Type "%~f0"^| Findstr.exe /BLIC:":::" 2^> nul ')Do (
   For /F "Tokens=2* Delims=[]" %%v in ("%%G")Do Echo(^|%%v^|
  ))>"%TEMP%\%~n0helpfile.~tmp"
  Type "%TEMP%\%~n0helpfile.~tmp" | More
  timeout /T 60 > nul
  Color 07
  If "%~2" == "DE" (Exit)Else Exit /B 1
 )
 If "!![" == "[" Call "%~f0" "/?" "DE"
:::[=====================================================================================================================]
:::[ cout /?                                                                                                             ]
:::[ %COUT% Cursor output macro.                                                                                         ]
:::[ * Valid Args for COUT: {/Y:Argvalue} {/X:Argvalue} {/S:Argvalue} {/C:Argvalue}                                      ]
:::[       - Args Must be encased in curly braces. Arg order does not matter ; Each Arg is optional.                     ]
:::[ * Valid Switches for COUT: /Save /Alt /Main                                                                         ]
:::[ /Save - Stores the Y and X position at the start of the current expansion to .lY and .lX variables                  ]
:::[ /Alt  - Switch console to alternate screen Buffer. Persists until /Main switch is used.                             ]
:::[ /Main - Restore console to main screen Buffer. Console default is the main buffer.                                  ]
:::[                                                                                                                     ]
:::[   USAGE:                                                                                                            ]
:::[ * ArgValue Options ; '#' is an integer:                                                                             ]
:::[   {/Y:up|down|#} {/Y:up#|down#|#} {/Y:#up|#down|#} {/X:left|right|#} {/X:left#|right#|#} {/X:#left|#right|#}        ]
:::[  * note: {/Y:option} {/X:option} - 1 option only per Arg.                                                           ]
:::[        - directions: 'up' 'down' 'left' 'right' are relative to the cursors last position.                          ]
:::[         - /Y and /X options - #direction or direction#:                                                             ]
:::[           Positions the cursor a number of cells from the current position in the given direction.                  ]
:::[           Example; To move the cursor 5 rows up in the same column, without displaying any new text:                ]
:::[            %COUT%{/Y:5up}                                                                                           ]
:::[        - '#' (Absolute position) is the column number {/X:#} or row number {/Y:#} the cursor                        ]
:::[         * Integers for absolute positions contained in variables must be Expanded: {/Y:%varname%}                   ]
:::[           is to be positioned at, allowing cursor position to be set on single or multiple axis.                    ]
:::[         * Absolute Y and X positions capped at line and column maximum of the console display.                      ]
:::[         * Exceeding the maximum Y positions the cursor at the start of the last line in the console display.        ]
:::[         * Exceeding the maximum X positions the cursor at the start of the next line                                ]
:::[                                                                                                                     ]
:::[   {/S:Output String} {/S:(-)Output String} {/S:Output String(+)} {/S:Output String(K)} {/S:Output String(.#.)}      ]
:::[  * note: (-) Hide or (+) Show the Cursor during output of the string.                                               ]
:::[          (K) Clears the row of text from the position (K) occurs.                                                   ]
:::[          Example; Delete 5 characters from the current row to the right of the curser:                              ]
:::[           %COUT%{/S:(.5.)}                                                                                          ]
:::[   {/C:VTcode} {/C:VTcode-VTcode} {/C:VTcode-VTcode-VTcode}                                                          ]
:::[  * note: Chain multiple graphics rendition codes using '-'                                                          ]
:::[  See:      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting      ]
:::[  See also: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html                                                     ]
:::[=====================================================================================================================]

============================================== :# PreScript variable definitions

rem /* generate Vitual Terminal Escape Control .Character */
 For /F %%a in ( 'Echo prompt $E ^| cmd' )Do Set "\E=%%a"
rem /* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences */
(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline variable for macro definitions. DO NOT MODIFY this line or above 2 lines. =%)

================== :# Screen Dimensions [Customise columns,lines using the mode command.]
 Mode 160,38 & Cls
rem /* Get screen dimensions [lines] [columns]. Must be done before delayed expansion is enabled. */
 For /F "tokens=1,2 Delims=:" %%G in ('Mode')Do For %%b in (%%H)Do For %%a in (%%G)Do Set "%%a=%%b"

rem /* NON ENGLISH VERSION USERS: You will need to manually set Columns and lines for their desired console size */
 If not defined columns (Set "columns=100"& Set "lines=30")

rem /* Cursor position codes - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#simple-cursor-positioning */
 Set "left=D"&Set "right=C"&Set "up=A"&set "down=B"
 For /L %%n in (1 1 %lines%)Do (Set "%%ndown=[%%nB"&Set "down%%n=[%%nB"& set "%%nup=[%%nA"&Set "up%%n=[%%nA")
 For /L %%n in (1 1 %columns%)Do (Set "%%nleft=[%%nD"&Set "left%%n=[%%nD"&set "%%nright=[%%nC"&set "right%%n=[%%nC")

%= Catch Args        =%Set COUT=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 ( %\n%
%= Test No Args       =%If "!Args!" == "" (CLS^&Echo/Usage Error. Args Required. ^& Call "%~f0" "/?" "Usage" ^|^| Exit /B 1) %\n%
%= Test Braces Used   =%If "!Args:}=!" == "!Args!" (CLS^&Echo/Usage Error. Args must be enclosed in curly braces ^& Call "%~f0" "/?" "Usage" ^|^| Exit /B 1) %\n%
%= Reset macro        =%Set ".Y=" ^& Set ".X=" ^& Set ".Str=" ^& Set ".C=" %\n%
%=  internal vars     =%Set "Arg1=" ^& Set "Arg2=" ^& Set "Arg3=" ^& Set "Arg4=" %\n%
%= Split Args.        =%For /F "Tokens=1,2,3,4 Delims={}" %%1 in ("!Args!")Do ( %\n%
%= Substring           =%Set "Arg1=%%~1" %\n%
%=  modification       =%Set "Arg2=%%~2" %\n%
%=  identifies Args    =%Set "Arg3=%%~3" %\n%
%=  during handling.   =%Set "Arg4=%%~4" %\n%
%=                    =%) %\n%
%= Check /Save switch =%If not "!Args:/Save=!" == "!Args!" (%\n%
%= Reset Cursor Save   =%Set ".Cpos=" ^&Set ".Char="%\n%
%= 10 char max; Repeat =%For /L %%l in (2 1 12)Do (%\n%
%= until R returned     =%If not "!.Char!" == "R" (%\n%
%= from esc[6n          =%^<nul set /p "=%\E%[6n" %\n%
%= Redirects to          =%FOR /L %%z in (1 1 %%l) DO pause ^< CON ^> NUL%\n%
%= prevent blocking      =%Set ".Char=;"%\n%
%= script execution      =%for /F "tokens=1 skip=1 delims=*" %%C in ('"REPLACE /W ? . < con"') DO (Set ".Char=%%C")%\n%
%= Append string w.out R =%If "!.Cpos!" == "" (Set ".Cpos=!.Char!")Else (set ".Cpos=!.Cpos!!.Char:R=!") %\n%
%=                      =%)%\n%
%=                     =%)%\n%
%= Split Captured Pos  =%For /F "tokens=1,2 Delims=;" %%X in ("!.Cpos!")Do Set ".lY=%%X" ^& Set ".LX=%%Y" %\n%
%= End of Pos /Save   =%)%\n%
%= Begin Arg          =%For %%i in (1 2 3 4)Do For %%S in (Y X C S)Do If not "!Arg%%i!" == "" ( %\n%
%= Processing. 4 Args   =%If not "!Arg%%i:/%%S:=!" == "!Arg%%i!" ( %\n%
%= Flagged with Y X C S  =%Set "Arg%%i=!Arg%%i:/%%S:=!" %\n%
%= Strip /Flag In Arg#   =%For %%v in ("!Arg%%i!")Do ( %\n%
%= /Y Lines Arg handling  =%If "%%S" == "Y" ( %\n%
%= Test if arg is variable =%If Not "!%%~v!" == "" ( %\n%
%= assign down / up value   =%Set ".Y=%\E%!%%~v!" %\n%
%= -OR-                    =%)Else ( %\n%
%= assign using operation   =%Set /A ".Y=!Arg%%i!" %\n%
%= to allow use of offsets; =%If !.Y! GEQ !Lines! (Set /A ".Y=Lines-1") %\n%
%= constrained to console   =%Set ".Y=%\E%[!.Y!d" %\n%
%= maximum lines.         =%)) %\n%
%= /X Cols Arg handling   =%If "%%S" == "X" ( %\n%
%= processing follows same =%If Not "!%%~v!" == "" ( %\n%
%= logic as /Y;            =%Set ".X=%\E%!%%~v!" %\n%
%= except if Columns     =%)Else ( %\n%
%= exceed console max     =%Set /A ".X=!Arg%%i!" %\n%
%= columns line wrapping   =%If !.X! GEQ !Columns! (Set ".X=1"^& Set ".Y=%\E%!Down!") %\n%
%= is effected.            =%Set ".X=%\E%[!.X!G" %\n%
%=                       =%)) %\n%
%= /C Color Arg Handling. %If "%%S" == "C" ( %\n%
%= Substituition          =%Set ".C=%\E%[!Arg%%i!" %\n%
%= replaces '-' with VT   =%Set ".C=!.C:-=m%\E%[!" %\n%
%= chain - m\E[           =%Set ".C=!.C!m" %\n%
%=                       =%) %\n%
%= /S String Arg Handle  =%If "%%S" == "S" ( %\n%
%=  Substitute Sub-Args   =%Set ".Str=!Arg%%i!" %\n%
%=  (-) hide cursor        =%Set ".Str=!.Str:(-)=%\E%[?25l!" %\n%
%=  (+) show cursor        =%Set ".Str=!.Str:(+)=%\E%[?25h!" %\n%
%=  (K) clear line         =%Set ".Str=!.Str:(K)=%\E%[K!" %\n%
%=  (.#.) delete # of      =%Set ".Str=!.Str:(.=%\E%[!" %\n%
%=  characters             =%Set ".Str=!.Str:.)=P!" %\n%
%=                       =%) %\n%
%= End Arg Handling   =%))) %\n%
%= /Main /Alt Switch  =%If not "!Args:/Main=!" == "!Args!" ( %\n%
%= handling for       =%^< nul Set /P "=%\E%[?1049l!.Y!!.X!!.C!!.Str!%\E%[0m" %\n%
%= switching console  =%)Else If not "!Args:/Alt=!" == "!Args!" ( %\n%
%= buffers. No Switch =%^< nul Set /P "=%\E%[?1049h!.Y!!.X!!.C!!.Str!%\E%[0m" %\n%
%= outputs to current =%)Else ( ^< nul Set /P "=!.Y!!.X!!.C!!.Str!%\E%[0m" ) %\n%
%= buffer.           =%)Else Set Args=
rem /* Simple subsecond delay macro. Uses call to a non existentent label # number of times to delay script execution. */
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic cpu get maxclockspeed /format:value')Do Set /A "%%G=%%H/20" 2> nul
 If not defined Maxclockspeed Set "Maxclockspeed=200"
 Set "Hash=#"& Set "delay=(If "!Hash!" == "#" (Set /A "Delay.len=Maxclockspeed")Else Set "Delay.len=#")& For /L %%i in (1 1 !Delay.Len!)Do call :[_false-label_] 2> Nul"

============================================== :# Script Body [Demo]
rem /* Enable Delayed Expansion after macro definiton in order to expand macro. */
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & CD "%TEMP%"
rem /* Usage examples */
 %COUT%{/X:10}{/Y:5}{/C:34}{"/S:(-)hello there^^^!"}
 %Delay%
rem /* Example use of mixed foreground / background color and other graphics rendition properties */
 %COUT%{"/C:31-1-4-48;2;0;80;130"}{/S:Bye for now.}{/Y:down}
 %Delay%
 %COUT%{/Y:up}{/C:35}{/S:again}{/X:16}
 %Delay%
 %COUT%{"/S:(K)^_^"}{/X:right}{/C:32}{/Y:down} /Save
 %Delay%
rem /* Switch to Alternate screen buffer: /Alt */
 %COUT%{"/S:(-)(K)o_o"}{/X:.lX+1}{/Y:6}{/C:33}{/Y:down} /Alt
 %Delay%
 %COUT%{"/S:Don't worry, they'll be back"}{/Y:down}{/X:15left}{/C:7-31}
rem /* Cursor position is tied to the active console buffer. The contents of the Alternate buffer are discarded when reverting to the Main buffer. */
 %Delay%
rem /* Return to Main screen buffer: /Main */
 %COUT%{/X:3left}{/Y:5up}{"/S:That's all folks."} /Save /Main
rem /* Cursor position is tied to the active console buffer. */
 %Delay%
rem /* restore cursor position /Save .lX value with +7 offset ; Overwrite all and delete 6 following characters:(.6.) ; restore cursor: (+) */
     %COUT%{/X:10left}{/S:How(.6.)(+)}{/C:32}
rem /* The same as the above line using VT codes manually. */
 ::: <nul Set /P "=%\E%[10D%\E%[32mHow%\E%[6P%\E%[?25l"
 %Delay%
 %COUT%{/Y:100}
 Endlocal
 Goto :eof
```

An alternate version of the above macro that uses a structure for arg handling that is simpler and has better readability can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/GL87S8fF).

Answer (score 3):

Solution for changing the foreground and background colors and writing without new lines.
It does not create any temporary files.

No special editors are required, so Notepad can be used for editing.
[image: Output on Windows 10]

The first parameter for the **:color** subroutine is the color code, the rest of the (optional) parameters are the text to display. If the last parameter is **$** then a new line is written at the end.
The color codes are the same as for the [color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/color) command.
The **:echo** subroutine can be used to display a text without new line (unlike regular echo).

```
@echo off
call :color 4
call :echo Red foreground
call :color 7 " and "
call :color 4f
echo Red background

call :color 
echo Back to normal

call :color 70 "Black "
call :color 1 "Blue "
call :color 2 "Green "
call :color 3 "Aqua "
call :color 4 "Red "
call :color 5 "Purple "
call :color 6 "Yellow "
call :color 7 "White "
call :color 8 "Gray "
call :color 9 "LightBlue" $
call :color a "LightGreen "
call :color b "LightAqua "
call :color c "LightRed "
call :color d "LightPurple "
call :color e "LightYellow "
call :color f "BrightWhite " $

call :color 1f Blue back
call :color 2f Green back
call :color 3f Aqua back
call :color 4f Red back
call :color 5f Purple back
call :color 6f Yellow back
call :color 7f White back
call :color 8f Gray back
call :color 9f "LightBlue back" $
call :color a0 LightGreen back
call :color b0 LightAqua back
call :color c0 LightRed back
call :color d0 LightPurple back
call :color e0 LightYellow back
call :color f0 LightWhite back $

call :color
echo %ESC%[4mUnderline%ESC%[0m.
pause 


goto :eof

:: Displays a text without new line at the end (unlike echo)
:echo
@<nul set /p ="%*"
@goto :eof

:: Change color to the first parameter (same codes as for the color command) 
:: And display the other parameters (write $ at the end for new line)
:color
@echo off
IF [%ESC%] == [] for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"
SET color=0%1
IF [%color%] == [0] SET color=07
SET fore=%color:~-1%
SET back=%color:~-2,1% 
SET color=%ESC%[
if %fore% LEQ 7 (
  if %fore% == 0 SET color=%ESC%[30
  if %fore% == 1 SET color=%ESC%[34
  if %fore% == 2 SET color=%ESC%[32
  if %fore% == 3 SET color=%ESC%[36
  if %fore% == 4 SET color=%ESC%[31
  if %fore% == 5 SET color=%ESC%[35
  if %fore% == 6 SET color=%ESC%[33
  if %fore% == 7 SET color=%ESC%[37
) ELSE (
  if %fore% == 8 SET color=%ESC%[90
  if %fore% == 9  SET color=%ESC%[94
  if /i %fore% == a SET color=%ESC%[92
  if /i %fore% == b SET color=%ESC%[96
  if /i %fore% == c SET color=%ESC%[91
  if /i %fore% == d SET color=%ESC%[95
  if /i %fore% == e SET color=%ESC%[93
  if /i %fore% == f SET color=%ESC%[97
)
if %back% == 0 (SET color=%color%;40) ELSE (
  if %back% == 1 SET color=%color%;44
  if %back% == 2 SET color=%color%;42
  if %back% == 3 SET color=%color%;46
  if %back% == 4 SET color=%color%;41
  if %back% == 5 SET color=%color%;45
  if %back% == 6 SET color=%color%;43
  if %back% == 7 SET color=%color%;47
  if %back% == 8 SET color=%color%;100
  if %back% == 9  SET color=%color%;104
  if /i %back% == a SET color=%color%;102
  if /i %back% == b SET color=%color%;106
  if /i %back% == c SET color=%color%;101
  if /i %back% == d SET color=%color%;105
  if /i %back% == e SET color=%color%;103
  if /i %back% == f SET color=%color%;107
)
SET color=%color%m
:repeatcolor
if [%2] NEQ [$] SET color=%color%%~2
shift
if [%2] NEQ [] if [%2] NEQ [$] SET color=%color% & goto :repeatcolor
if [%2] EQU [$] (echo %color%) else (<nul set /p ="%color%")
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use cecho.. you can also use it to embed right into your script so you dont have to carry along a .com or .exe

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files

Answer (score 2):

A *fast* alternative to color **efficiently** with cmd batch since *Windows XP* by using PowerShell as a subprocess linked to the console output through a named pipe. It can be done with FindStr too, but PowerShell offers more options and seems quicker.

The main interest in keeping PowerShell as a subprocess, using a pipe to communicate, is that the display is **far more faster** than launching PowerShell or FindStr for each line to display.

Other good points :

- No need for temporary files
- Echoing though a pipe permits the display of the full ASCII table without bothering escapes.
- Works fine with fd redirection. To color only stderr as example, or to redirect to a file / other process.

Here is a sample code for doing that :

```batch
::
:: Launch a PowerShell child process in the background linked to the console and 
:: earing through named pipe PowerShellCon_%PID%
::
:: Parameters :
::   [ PID ] : Console Process ID used as an identifier for the named pipe, launcher PID by default.
::   [ timeout ] : Subprocess max life in seconds, 300 by default. If -1, the subprocess
::                  will not terminate while the process %PID% is still alive.
:: Return :
::   0 if the child PowerShell has been successfully launched and the named pipe is available.
::   1 if it fails.
::   2 if we can't get a PID.
::   3 if PowerShell is not present or doesn't work.
::
:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess
  SET LOCALV_PID=
  SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=300
  IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET LOCALV_PID=%~1
  IF NOT "%~2" == "" SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=%~2
  powershell -command "$_" 2>&1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" EXIT /B 3
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" (
    FOR /F %%P IN ('powershell -command "$parentId=(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId; write-host (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$parentId).ParentProcessId;"') DO (
      SET LOCALV_PID=%%P
    )
  )
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" EXIT /B 2
  START /B powershell -command "$cmdPID=$PID; Start-Job -ArgumentList $cmdPID -ScriptBlock { $ProcessActive = $true; $timeout=!LOCALV_TIMEOUT!; while((!LOCALV_TIMEOUT! -eq -1 -or $timeout -gt 0) -and $ProcessActive) { Start-Sleep -s 1; $timeout-=1; $ProcessActive = Get-Process -id !LOCALV_PID! -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; } if ($timeout -eq 0 -or ^! $ProcessActive) { Stop-Process -Id $args; } } | Out-Null ; $npipeServer = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream('PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In); Try { $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeServer); while(($msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()) -notmatch 'QUIT') { $disp='write-host '+$msg+';'; invoke-expression($disp); $npipeServer.Disconnect(); $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); }; } Finally { $npipeServer.Dispose(); }" 2>NUL
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=20 >NUL
  :LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep -m 50}"
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=!LOCALV_TRY! - 1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" cmd /C "ECHO -NoNewLine|MORE 1>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!" 2>NUL || GOTO:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  IF "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" EXIT /B 1
  EXIT /B 0
```

This "code" is written with delayed expansion **ON** but can be rewrite to work without it. There is many security points to consider, do not use it directly *in the wild*.

How to use it :

```batch
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO Extension inapplicable
  EXIT /B 1
)
::
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO Expansion inapplicable
  EXIT /B 1
)
CALL:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 EXIT /B 1
CALL:Color Cyan "I write this in Cyan"
CALL:Blue "I write this in Blue"
CALL:Green "And this in green"
CALL:Red -nonewline "And mix Red"
CALL:Yellow "with Yellow"
CALL:Green "And not need to trouble with ()<>&|;,%""^ and so on..."
EXIT /B 0
:Color
ECHO -foregroundcolor %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Blue
ECHO -foregroundcolor Blue %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Green
ECHO -foregroundcolor Green %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Red
ECHO -foregroundcolor Red %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
:Yellow
ECHO -foregroundcolor Yellow %*>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!
ECHO[|SET /P=>NUL
GOTO:EOF
::
:: Launch a PowerShell child process in the background linked to the console and 
:: earing through named pipe PowerShellCon_%PID%
::
:: Parameters :
::   [ PID ] : Console Process ID used as an identifier for the named pipe, launcher PID by default.
::   [ timeout ] : Subprocess max life in seconds, 300 by default. If -1, the subprocess
::                  will not terminate while the process %PID% is still alive.
:: Return :
::   0 if the child PowerShell has been successfully launched and the named pipe is available.
::   1 if it fails.
::   2 if we can't get a PID.
::   3 if PowerShell is not present or doesn't work.
::
:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess
  SET LOCALV_PID=
  SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=300
  IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET LOCALV_PID=%~1
  IF NOT "%~2" == "" SET LOCALV_TIMEOUT=%~2
  powershell -command "$_" 2>&1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" EXIT /B 3
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" (
    FOR /F %%P IN ('powershell -command "$parentId=(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId; write-host (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$parentId).ParentProcessId;"') DO (
      SET LOCALV_PID=%%P
    )
  )
  IF "!LOCALV_PID!" == "" EXIT /B 2
  START /B powershell -command "$cmdPID=$PID; Start-Job -ArgumentList $cmdPID -ScriptBlock { $ProcessActive = $true; $timeout=!LOCALV_TIMEOUT!; while((!LOCALV_TIMEOUT! -eq -1 -or $timeout -gt 0) -and $ProcessActive) { Start-Sleep -s 1; $timeout-=1; $ProcessActive = Get-Process -id !LOCALV_PID! -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; } if ($timeout -eq 0 -or ^! $ProcessActive) { Stop-Process -Id $args; } } | Out-Null ; $npipeServer = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream('PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In); Try { $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeServer); while(($msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()) -notmatch 'QUIT') { $disp='write-host '+$msg+';'; invoke-expression($disp); $npipeServer.Disconnect(); $npipeServer.WaitForConnection(); }; } Finally { $npipeServer.Dispose(); }" 2>NUL
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=20 >NUL
  :LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep -m 50}"
  SET /A LOCALV_TRY=!LOCALV_TRY! - 1 >NUL
  IF NOT "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" cmd /C "ECHO -NoNewLine|MORE 1>\\.\pipe\PowerShellCon_!LOCALV_PID!" 2>NUL || GOTO:LaunchPowerShellSubProcess_WaitForPipe
  IF "!LOCALV_TRY!" == "0" EXIT /B 1
  EXIT /B 0
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604485/3641635) to my original answer on the same topic.

Comment: You have posted much the same answer to a number of questions. Please, in future, refrain from doing this and, when you have earned sufficient reputation, just post a link to your original answer in a comment.

Comment: @AdrianMole Noted. The page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258303/how-can-i-use-the-color-command-when-run-from-cmd-in-a-batch-file-only-applies) shows that duplicate questions can be grouped, maybe a comment on this page would have sufficed ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the following lines into a file called `ColourText.bas` on your desktop.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module MyApplication  
Public Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStdHandle" (ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetConsoleTextAttribute Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetConsoleTextAttribute" (ByVal hConsoleOutput As Long, ByVal wAttributes As Long) As Long
Public Const STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12&
Public Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10&
Public Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11&

Sub Main()
    Dim hOut as Long
    Dim Ret as Long
    Dim Colour As Long
    Dim Colour1 As Long
    Dim Text As String
    hOut  = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    Colour = CLng("&h" & Split(Command(), " ")(0))
    Colour1 = Clng("&h" & Split(Command(), " ")(1))
    Text = Mid(Command(), 7)
    Ret = SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut,  Colour)
    Console.Out.WriteLine(text)
    Ret = SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, Colour1)
End Sub
End Module
```

Save it and type the following in a command prompt.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%userprofile%\desktop\ColourText.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop\ColourText.bas" /verbose
```

A file called ColourText.exe will appear on your desktop. **Move it to the Windows folder**.

To use you must use two character codes to set colour eg `01` not `1`.

```
ColourText ColourOfText ColourOfTextWhenFinished Text
```

EG To set blue on white by not passing any text, then red on white text, finishing with blue on grey.

```
ColourText F1 F1
ColourText F2 71 This is green on white
```

or

```
ColourText F1 F1
cls
ColourText F4 F4
Echo Hello
Echo Hello today
ColourText F1 F1
```

Also the `CLS` command becomes interesting. `Color` command without parameters resets all colours to startup colours.

To get the colour code add the following numbers together. Use Calculator in programmers mode. These are hex numbers. They can be added together eg Red + Blue + FG Intensity = 13 = D. As 10+ wasn't used the background will be black. Colour codes MUST be two characters, eg `08` not `8`.

```
FOREGROUND_RED = &H4     '  text color contains red.
FOREGROUND_INTENSITY = &H8     '  text color is intensified.
FOREGROUND_GREEN = &H2     '  text color contains green.
FOREGROUND_BLUE = &H1     '  text color contains blue.
BACKGROUND_BLUE = &H10    '  background color contains blue.
BACKGROUND_GREEN = &H20    '  background color contains green.
BACKGROUND_INTENSITY = &H80    '  background color is intensified.
BACKGROUND_RED = &H40    '  background color contains red.
```

Comment: While interesting, not everyone will have the SDK installed, in fact, very few people, I think.

Comment: No SDK required to compile as csc.exe, jsc, vbc.exe are included with standart .NET 4.5+ install..

Answer (score 1):

I just converted from Win 7 Home to Win 10 Pro and wanted to replace the batch I call from other batches to echo info in color. Reviewing what is discussed above I use the following which will directly replace my previous batch. NOTE the addition of "~" to the message so that messages with spaces may be used. Instead of remembering codes I use letters for the colors I needed.

If %2 contains spaces requires "..."
%1 Strong Colors on black: R=Red G=GREEN Y=YELLOW  W=WHITE

```
ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="R" ECHO ^[91m%~2[0m
IF "%1"=="G" ECHO ^[92m%~2[0m
IF "%1"=="Y" ECHO ^[93m%~2[0m
IF "%1"=="W" ECHO ^[97m%~2[0m
```

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of combinations you can create for what ever your needs are. I messed around with color combinations for years and created this sample script as a reference. Feel free to mess around with the FOR Loop (Start,Incr,End) for your needs.. Remember there are also many Esc[x that default to your Terminal settings and have no significant value. I have omitted a lot of that in the script below.
"ColorLoopEcho.cmd"  Have fun:
:: Note the UTF-8 ASCI character  is the [ESC] character representing the esc needed for this to work. e.g. Press and hold ALT+27 (Depending on your Character set)

```
@echo off&cls
:: START "ColorLoopEchoTest" /D "%OneDrive%\" /High /B "%OneDrive%\Batch\ColorLoopEchoTest.cmd"
SETLOCAL enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
SET a=0&SET b=0&SET c=0`enter code here`
SET x=[
SET xc=[0m
SET x33=%x%33m&SET x41=%x%41m&SET x92=%x%92m&SET x10193=%x%101;93m&SET x2192=%x%21;92m&SET x8100=%x%8;100m
echo =====================================================================================================
echo Color LOOP TEST and Inner Loop Test 
echo =====================================================================================================
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                    %xc%
SET /a a=!a!+1&SET x41=%x%41m
echo %x33%%date% %time%%xc%     %x41% !a!: %xc%
::echo =====================================================================================================
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (
  echo %xc%%x36% Color Counter:    %xc%%x32%^<ESC^>[%%im  [%%im  %%i %xc%
)
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                    %xc%
SET /a a=!a!+1&SET x41=%x%41m
echo %x33%%date% %time%%xc%     %x41% !a!: %xc%
SET x2192=%x%21;92m
::echo =====================================================================================================
FOR /L %%i IN (30,1,39) DO (
  echo %xc%%x36% Color Counter:    %xc%%x32%^<ESC^>[%%im  [%%im  %%i %xc%
)
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                    %xc%
SET /a a=!a!+1&SET x41=%x%41m
echo %x33%%date% %time%%xc%     %x41% !a!: %xc%
SET x2192=%x%21;92m
::echo =====================================================================================================
FOR /L %%i IN (40,1,48) DO (
  echo %xc%%x36% Color Counter:    %xc%%x32%^<ESC^>[%%im  [%%im  %%i %xc%
)
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                    %xc%
SET /a a=!a!+1&SET x41=%x%41m
echo %x33%%date% %time%%xc%     %x41% !a!: %xc%
SET x2192=%x%21;92m
::echo =====================================================================================================
FOR /L %%j IN (90,1,107) DO (
  echo %xc%%x36% Color Counter:    %xc%%x32%^<ESC^>[%%jm  [%%jm  %%j %xc%
)
SET x2192=%x%21;92m
SET /a a=!a!+1&SET x41=%x%41m
echo %x33%%date% %time%%xc%     %x41% !a!: %xc%
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                    %xc%
FOR /L %%k IN (90,1,107) DO (
    FOR /L %%l IN (30,1,48) DO (
    echo %x36% Color Counter 2: %xc% %x32%^<ESC^>[%%k;%%lm  [%%k;%%lm  %%k;%%l %xc%
    )
  echo %xc% %x8100%                                          %xc%
  echo %x91% Color Counter 1: %xc% %x93%^<ESC^>[%%km     [%%km     %%k %xc%
)
::echo =====================================================================================================
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                         %xc%
echo %x101%START "Edit" /D "%odl%" /High /B Notepad++ %cmd% %xc%
echo %x105%FileName:               %~ftza0 %xc%
echo %xc% %x2192%                                                                                                         %xc%
echo %x92%START "ColorLoopEchoTest" /D "%odl%" /High /B %cmd% %xc%

TIMEOUT /T 1
EndLocal
:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this working on Windows 10, you can enable this flag: `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`.

With this registry key you can set this by default

`[HKCU\Console] VirtualTerminalLevel dword 0x1`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use **NodeJS**.

Here is an example:

```
const os = require('os');
const colors = require('colors');

console.log("Operative System:".green,os.type(),os.release());
console.log("Uptime:".blue,os.uptime());
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Nice but OP still asked about batch, not node.js.

Answer (score 0):

*Setting color to the log statements in powershell is not a big deal friend.*
you can use `-ForegroundColor` parameter.

**To write a confirmation message.**

```
Write-Host "Process executed Successfully...." -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

**To write an error message.**

```
Write-Host "Sorry an unexpected error occurred.." -ForegroundColor Red
```

**To write a progress message**.

```
Write-Host "Working under pocess..." -ForegroundColor Green
```

Answer (score 0):

```
call :color_echo "blue" "blue txt"
call :color_echo "red" "red txt"
echo "white txt"


REM : https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php
:color_echo
    @echo off

    set "color=%~1"
    set "txt=%~2"

    set ESC=
    set black=%ESC%[30m
    set red=%ESC%[31m
    set green=%ESC%[32m
    set yellow=%ESC%[33m
    set blue=%ESC%[34m
    set magenta=%ESC%[35m
    set cyan=%ESC%[36m
    set white=%ESC%[37m

    if "%~1" == "black"   set "color=!black!"
    if "%~1" == "red"     set "color=!red!"
    if "%~1" == "green"   set "color=!green!"
    if "%~1" == "yellow"  set "color=!yellow!"
    if "%~1" == "blue"    set "color=!blue!"
    if "%~1" == "magenta" set "color=!magenta!"
    if "%~1" == "cyan"    set "color=!cyan!"
    if "%~1" == "white"   set "color=!white!"

    echo | set /p="!color!!txt!"
    echo.

    REM : return to standard white color
    echo | set /p="!white!"

    REM : exiting the function only
    EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: `%ESC%` is empty, so this won't work. `echo !white!` sets the color to white. To return to the default colors (whatever the usersettings for that are): the `color` command without parameters does that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is make a system call to powershell like this :

```
s=os.system('powershell Write-Host "I am so bored with this. Work already" -ForegroundColor Blue')
```

otherwise :

```
←[94mPff
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in batch file:

```
:: Sets the ESC character  
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"

echo %ESC%[91m Red %ESC%[0m
echo %ESC%[94m Blue %ESC%[0m
echo %ESC%[91m My text in Red. %ESC%[0m
```

See the selected answer for all the color code combinations.

Answer (score 0):

here is a VB project that you can compile and make color codes in batch files, i used Rosyln to compile. cmd line was "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn/vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%name%.exe" "%1" /verbose
here is the code that is working, note that some of the code came from AI sources (fixing errors). after reading the article, think this will be deleted. the executable works perfectly under all conditions.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module ColourText
    Public Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStdHandle" (ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function SetConsoleTextAttribute Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetConsoleTextAttribute" (ByVal hConsoleOutput As Long, ByVal wAttributes As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo" (ByVal hConsoleOutput As Long, ByRef lpConsoleScreenBufferInfo As CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO) As Long
    Public Const STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12&
    Public Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10&
    Public Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11&

    Public Structure CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
        Public dwSize As COORD
        Public dwCursorPosition As COORD
        Public wAttributes As Integer
        Public srWindow As SMALL_RECT
        Public dwMaximumWindowSize As COORD
    End Structure

    Public Structure COORD
        Public X As Short
        Public Y As Short
    End Structure

    Public Structure SMALL_RECT
        Public Left As Short
        Public Top As Short
        Public Right As Short
        Public Bottom As Short
    End Structure

    Sub Main()
        Dim hOut as Long
        Dim Ret as Long
        Dim Colour As Long
        Dim Colour1 As Long
        Dim Text As String
        Dim args() As String = Split(Command(), " ")

        If args.Length < 3 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide two hexadecimal color values and a text string as command line arguments.")
            Return
        End If

        hOut  = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
        Dim csbi As CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, csbi)
        Dim originalColor As Integer = csbi.wAttributes

        Colour = Convert.ToInt32(args(0), 16)
        Colour1 = Convert.ToInt32(args(1), 16)
        Text = Mid(Command(), 7)
        Ret = SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut,  Colour)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(text)
        Ret = SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut, originalColor)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use the color command to change the color of the whole console

```
Color 0F
```

Is black and white

```
Color 0A
```

Is black and green

Comment: Nice to know. Unfortunately this changes the color of the whole console and the question is how to change a single line (or a part of it)..

Comment: The OP has stated that he is familiar with this command and that the problem is that it changes the entire console and not a specific line.

Comment: Yes indeed not truly responsive, but that's still useful to know.