# In batch, how do I create spaces at the beginning of a input prompt string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's say I have a batch file that has "padding" in it, and I want to indent the beginning of the prompt string for the user to type in. If I use spaces, it will not show up when run, it just ignores the spaces. This script for an example:

```
@echo off

echo.
echo.
echo    Hi.
echo    Please input something.
echo.
set /P input=
```

After the `=` there is three spaces, and what I expect is that the marker for input is away from the edge of the command box, however these spaces are ignored.

How can I fix this problem? I am using Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: Have you tried (set /p input=  ) ?

Comment: It worked for me in Windows XP SP3 (can't say for any other version at the moment). I mean, when the execution stopped for reading my input, the cursor was three spaces from the edge of the command window.

Comment: Yes, I believe it might be broken on Vista+

Comment: @Andiry M - I'm using Windows 7, this might be the reason why. It would still be nice to have a solution for this, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the comments above state, Vista and beyond strip leading spaces in a SET /P prompt.

The way to get around the problem is to define and use a backspace character in the prompt.

```
::define a variable containing a single backspace character
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set BS=%%A

set /p var=%BS%   Leading spaces will not show properly.
```

Normally the prompt will be at the beginning of a line, so the above works just fine.

But if the prompt is issued from the middle of a line (very unusual), then a leading character should be included prior to the `<BS>`, since the backspace will erase whatever was before it.

```
<nul set/p=Leave the cursor at the end of this line:
set /p var=.%BS%   The dot (any char) is necessary to prevent the <BS> from erasing the :
```

Answer (score 35):

You need to add a dot after the echo
The following example will output "Test" with three leading spaces:

```
echo.   Test
```

Same works for tabulator. The following example will output "Test" with one leading tab:

```
echo.   Test
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in Windows 10

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's about adding spaces without line feed with `set /p`. How it can get more upvotes than the correct, accepted answer from dbenham?

Comment: Because it works exactly the way the original question asked - without unnecessary program steps or gymnastics - and the set /P isn't necessary.
Using "echo.", you can follow the "." with as many leading spaces as you wish.  I have verified that this works in Win-10 Pro.
Note that I have not verified this by exporting to a file, limiting myself to the scope of OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

Highly inspired by in dbenham's answer, I propose a similar but simpler variation based in the fact that the backspace character can be inserted in its raw form (only in batch files, attempting this in the console directly won't work as expected):

`set /p var=.'BS'  Leading spaces will now show properly.`

The 'BS' character can be inserted by typing Alt + Numpad 008 (8 is backspace's ASCII code, won't work using the alphanumeric keys typically found above the letters), using a **good** text editor (such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), Windows Notepad simply performs the backspace action).

If unable to *insert* the **character**, Notepad++ has a useful feature for this: in  *TextFX* menu, choose *TextFX Tools* followed by *Insert Ascii Chart or Character*:
[image: Insert Ascii Chart or character]
The desired character is the `BS` (white letters on black background on the screenshot) found in line 9 (ASCII character `8` - as stated above - as it's a zero-indexed table).

If *still* the result is **not** the one described, try changing the file encoding to ASCII. Using Notepad++:

1. Make a backup copy of the script or perform an experiment in a separate file, as non-ASCII characters (accented character, non-Latin etc.) are **lost** in this conversion.
2. In *Encoding* menu, choose *Convert to ANSI*
3. Save and check the result again...

Tested with Windows 7 Professional SP1.

Credits also go to:

- @DavidCallanan for questioning the obtained result.
- Wadelau for [writing about Notepad++ at *ufqi.com*](http://ufqi.com/blog/notepad-datetime-ascii-tips/) (where the screenshot was extracted from).

Comment: I tried this but after running the file I see this: `.Ôùÿ  Leading spaces will now show properly.`

Comment: @DavidCallanan: Note that the `'BS'` is a single character

Comment: I know, and I got the special backspace character to show up, however when I run the code the result is `.Ôùÿ Leading spaces will now show` instead of ` Leading spaces will now show`

Comment: @DavidCallanan - please take a look at the "file encoding" tip which was recently added to the answer. If that doesn't work, please share your code page - get it by running `cmd.exe` and typing `mode`.

Comment: Nit: even easier/more practical than the _Insert Ascii Chart or Character_ feature, in Notepad++ one may simply get the _ASCII Insertion Panel_ by going to _Edit_ menu and choose _Character Panel_. Then simply select the desired entry (`7`/`BEL` in this case) and double-click to insert at the cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

This works in every Windows OS from W2K + I've tried, if it suits you.
You could just use a : in the string.

```
set /p "var=Please input something: "
echo.%var%
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%a in ('ECHO prompt $E ^| cmd') do (
    SET "ESC=%%a"
)
SET /p input=!ESC![0m   Give me some space  
ECHO Your input was "%input%"
ECHO.
ECHO To prevent trailing spaces beeing removed (e. g. by a formatter) you can also do something like:
SET /p input=!ESC![0m   Give me some space  !ESC![0m
ECHO This should be enough. But there is some more:
ECHO.
SET /p=!ESC![44m    Give me more space and color
SET /p="!ESC![0;95m        !ESC![4mGive me more space, color and spe(ia| (haracters and trailling space     "
SET /p="!ESC![0;104m          Give me more space, color and spe(ia| (haracters but please !ESC![0mstop the colors"
```

[image: Terminal output]

The last two cases requires double quotes due to some special characters. They could also be escaped with a circumflex (e. g. `^|`) but if you have a lot of them it will become messy. The given solutions do not work (nicely) with quotation marks.

This solution relies heavily on this (awesome) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38617204/16104038

Answer (score 0):

dbenhams answer works good when you only want to display the text, but not if you create a file, as it inputs also the backspaces.

But for files(and for displaying) you can use `copy /a` to remove a CR/LF with the help of a SUB(EOF) character.
The trick is to append the `SUB` character directly after the text, so it's just before the `CR/LF` of the ECHO output.
And then using the `/a` switch of the copy command will only copy the content to the SUB character, so the `SUB` and also the `CR/LF` are removed

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :createSub
call :echoWithoutLinefeed "=hello"
call :echoWithoutLinefeed " world"
exit /b

:echoWithoutLinefeed
> txt.tmp (echo(%~1!sub!)
copy txt.tmp /a txt2.tmp /b > nul
type txt2.tmp
del txt.tmp txt2.tmp
exit /b

:createSub
copy nul sub.tmp /a > nul
for /F %%a in (sub.tmp) DO (
   set "sub=%%a"
)
del sub.tmp
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **double quotes** (" ... ") for your purpose

```
set /p OPTION="Your choice:   "
```

[As you can see here, the cursor for input is 3 units away.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR2VN.png)

Comment: Did you read the title `at the **beginning** of a input prompt string`?