# How can I preserve entered indent spaces in batch on user prompt?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get input whilst outputting over multiple lines, for example:

```
set /p var="Please enter a value:

    "
```

The user should type on the third line at the speech mark `"`, but instead it makes the user type after the colon `:`.

Or alternatively I could use:

```
echo Please enter a value:
echo.
set /p var="    "
```

But the indent isn't retained in the output.

Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT:

Would it be possible to use a blank space or black character instead of the first space, if so, which one?

Comment: For your 2nd approach: `set /P var="""` or `set /P var=""^"` should do it; to get the leading spaces things become more complicated since `set /P` trims them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In batch, how do I create spaces at the beginning of a input prompt string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864620/in-batch-how-do-i-create-spaces-at-the-beginning-of-a-input-prompt-string)

Comment: I would typically use an unobtrusive leading character `set /p var=.    "` or `set /p var=:    "`.  But if you really need it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864620/in-batch-how-do-i-create-spaces-at-the-beginning-of-a-input-prompt-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@echo off

set /p ^"var=Please enter a value:^

^

     ^"
```

Perhaps clearer:

```
@echo off

set /p ^"var=Please enter a value:^
%empty line%
^
%empty line%
     ^"
```