# Rundeck logs in Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, logging, console, rundeck

Rundeck jobs are triggered through Jenkins. How to get the colored output of Rundeck logs in Jenkins console?

Installed Ansi color plugin in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Jenkins Rundeck plugin takes the Rundeck format in text mode, without any format [to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931879/10426011). Using a Rundeck colored output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmzaW.jpg), the Jenkins output always takes as a [text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGuWx.jpg) (using the ANSI color plugin). This looks good for an enhancement request.