# Ansicon doesn't work with Windows 8

Tags: ruby, windows, 64-bit

Ansicon does not seem to want to work with Windows 8.

1 - I install it correctly : `ansicon -i` under the x64 directory (since I have Win 8 on a 64-bit machine/install),
2 - I launch a new command window, run `rspec` to run unit tests in ruby

Result - the ANSI characters are still displaying the raw unconverted data.

Any help would be appreciated; thanks.

Comment: stackoverflow fail? :-(

Comment: Really?  No one knows how to do this?  It's becoming quite a pain in my backside at work, trying to show my unit-test failures to my colleagues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `ansicon` might not have installed correctly. I've got `ansicon` working well on Windows 8 64-bit with Ruby 1.9.3p392.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Rc8.jpg

Try running `ansicon -i` from an elevated Command Prompt and see if that makes any difference. If you don't have administrator permissions, run `ansicon -p` to hook into the parent process for the current session and then see if `rspec` returns colored output then.

If you still can't get it to work, maybe try reinstalling the latest version of `ansicon`. I installed the 64-bit files (`ANSI32.dll`, `ANSI64.dll`, `ansicon.exe`, `ANSI-LLW.exe`) in my Ruby's `bin` directory so I know it's in my PATH.

Comment: I also have ansicon 1.61 running on Windows 8 (x64) but I had to add the ansicon folder to my path environment variable for it to work. Cheers.

Comment: I had this same problem.  I added x64 to my path, even set it to the very first library, and it did nothing.  However, I used the ansicon -p command and it started working.  Since the ansicon command worked, it was obviously in my path.  The documentation implies just adding it to the path should enable it, but that didn't work for me.  I just added ansicon -p to my startup batch file and now it works every time.  I didn't really want to do the -I option, at least for now.  With -p, it only impacts my Ruby environment and that is desirable.

Comment: @Tosk, see the edit I made to your post.  Works now, took me a while.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I did a cheap trick and just made a shorcut directly on my desktop in order to use it.
adding it to the path crashed ruby.