# batch - color input by user

Tags: batch-file

Hi im making a program that will launch a program from a folder. Here's the code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
title Launcher
call :ColorText 0a "Launcher"
echo.
:CMD
set /p cmd=">>> "
if not defined cmd goto CMD
call "%CD%"\bin\%cmd%
echo %cmd%>"%CD%\Commands_Log\%cmd%
goto CMD
:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

I really want to know how to color the user's input. For example my prompt goes like

> C:\ > abcd

Now, how do I color only the "abcd" part??

EDIT: I want it to be colored as it is being typed. This was my original question for everyone who didn't understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: There is no conventional method to do this, but you could put a choice command in that adds the letter they put in to a variable that is then displayed in a different color. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: @Vicky It ain't a duplicate...here i want the input to be colored....ONLY the input....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Prof Pickle comment you need to write your own key input, and then output each key with a color.

Coloring in batch can be done with Findstr described [how to have multiple colors in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/463115)
Get a single Key can be done with xcopy.

```
@echo off
call :color_init
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:keyLoop
call :GetKey
if not defined key exit /b
call :color 1a key
goto :keyLoop


:GetKey
set "key="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`xcopy /L /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>NUL`) do (
  if not defined key set "key=%%L"
)
set "key=%key:~-1%"
exit /b

:color_init
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
rem Prepare a file "X" with only one dot
<nul > X set /p ".=."
exit /b

:color
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param=!%~2!"
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
endlocal
exit /b

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('echo hello') do set "var=%%A"
echo %var%
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with [**cmdcolor**](https://github.com/jeremejevs/cmdcolor). Just `echo \033[93m` right before the input, and then `echo \033[0m` afterwards. Everything typed in between those echoes will be in yellow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a program called cecho.bat
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files