# get letter (X) of (TEXT) in batch

Tags: batch-file, letter

I'm making a password mask  in batch, but I need to get a certain letter of a variable for it to work. I am running Windows 7. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
title Password
set Pass=
set Letters=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

:Loop
cls
echo.
echo Password: %Pass%
choice /c:%Letters% /n
for /l %%a in (1,1,26) do if %errorlevel%==%%a set Pass=%Pass% (Letter %%a of %Letters%)
goto Loop
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282223 is a phenomenal password masker.

Comment: Just saying that It's helpful to ask the question, in your question.

Comment: here you can find few maskers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24396149/388389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
REM title Password
set Pass=
set Letters=#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0

:Loop
cls
echo.
echo Password: %Pass%
choice /c:%Letters:~1% /n
IF ERRORLEVEL 27 GOTO :EOF 
for /l %%a in (1,1,26) do if %errorlevel%==%%a CALL set Pass=%Pass% %%Letters:~%%a,1%%
goto Loop
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a how-to in batch.

The core of the method is `CALL set Pass=%Pass% %%Letters:~%%a,1%%`

This is a parsing trick. The argument to `call` is parsed as

- set
- Pass=originalvalueofpass<kbd>Space</kbd>
- %Letters:~*thevalueofawhenmatchwasfound*,1%

So, pressing `c` would make `errorlevel` and hence `%%a` = 3 when matched, so the `%letters:~%%a,1%` would be `%letters:~3,1%`

Using batch substringing. `%letters:~3,1%` means take the substring of `letters`, from position 3 for 1 character.

The substring syntax is

```
%var:~start,length% if start >=0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start >=0 and endpos <0
%var:~start,length% if start <0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start <0 and endpos <0
```

- length/endpos may be omitted. If omitted, the substring is "from the start position to the end"
- `%` may be `!` for `delayedexpansion` mode

But here's the difficulty: this substring method starts counting at `0` and we have `errorlevel` for the letter `c` = `3`. Using substringing, a=0,b=1,c=2,...

So we cheat by adding an extra character at the beginning of `letters`. Using this extra character, the letter produced by `%letters:~3,1%` is `c` as desired. I chose `#` - but any character would do.

Then we restore the `errorlevel` output from `choice` by using the substring of `letters` starting at position `1` (which is the original substring you used.)

Last little change is that I added an extra character to the end. I chose `0` and it's used as the `exit` character.

On entering `0`, errorlevel will be `27`, so we check for that value explicitly. If a `0` is entered, just exit from the procedure (it can be any label, of course) otherwise, it must be 1..26 so go check the alphabet.

Comment: I filtered through the code, removed two extra % signs, (It didn't work with them) but it gives me the value AFTER what I pressed, for example, when I press a, it types b.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the ':~1' in the 'choice' command. :p