# Python Beginner - How to customize the output window

Tags: python, windows

I am a beginner from a non programming background. I am using windows OS. Whenever I write a program in Python and run it, it opens in MS Dos with a black colored screen. I just want to change the background and the font color. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows command shell is pretty limited, it doesn't support the ANSI color codes that other OSes' shells do. But I found that the [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) module is extremely useful to get colors in Python command line interfaces.

Example from the website linked to above: 
[image]

And here's a colorful Hello World with code and output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the title bar of the command prompt. Go to properties. You can change all you want from Font & Color tabs there?

Answer (score 0):

For the whole window, http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Colours-in-Command-Prompt

For per-output colour, maybe something from here: [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line)