# Windows command line multiple colors for logging

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I'm routing my application logs to the windows cmd line window. It's hard to read I was just wondering if some kinda of plugin exists for the cmd line to color the text based on some rules for example timestamps in green, anything in `[]` as yellow, etc.

I'm not talking about routing the logs somewhere else more readable, but specifically if I can get the windows cmd line to be a more readable log target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: not duplicate, I'm looking for a 3rd party tool that can change the color "in-place" (without changing the logging code). if no answer after some time (doesn't exist) i can delete question myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free tool called SnakeTail that can tail log files and colorize the data in its application window based on regular expressions. You could use it instead of viewing log files from cmd.exe.

http://code.google.com/p/snaketail-net/

Comment: Just to emphasize, this is not a CLI tool (which I know is less important to a significant number of windows users).