# Using linux(ansi/vt100) color codes in C#

Tags: c#, colors, mono, console, vt100

I would like to use ANSI/VT100 in my C# output (on Linux/Mono PC). But

```
string colorme = @"\e[31mHello World\e[0m";
Console.WriteLine(colorme);
```

just results plain-text output in bash (i am using mono). Is it possible to use color codes like `\e[31m` in C# consolw programs on mono?

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't colour codes in window's command line. I could be wrong, though. You *can* change the colour of the terminal, but not via colour codes. This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line

Comment: Did you mean ansi or vt100?  Not the same thing, that's where the curses start.  Use the Console.ForegroundColor and BackgroundColor properties instead.

Comment: No, i mean i trying this example in Mono on Linux pc (ubuntu). But it does not work. Typing it in console works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ForegroundColor` and `Console.BackgroundColor` did not work with mono and my console so I was forced to use ANSI coloring.

The main issue is that C# doesn't know how to interpret the `\e` escape code. Since `\e` actually represents `\x1B` we can use the unicode escape code.

```cs
string colorme = "\x1b[31mHello World\x1b[0m";
Console.WriteLine(colorme);
```