# Why is my Laravel test terminal like this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Why is my terminal like this when I run `php artisan test`. I'm currently using the latest Laravel, Composer, and a Windows 7 machine. I saw vids on YouTube that also use Laravel tests, but their terminals are much cleaner.

[image: Laravel PHP artisan test on Windows 7]

Comment: If it helps , try Git Bash

Comment: Because windows basically. If you want the same output as `php artisan test`, try running `./vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox` or `vendor\bin\phpunit --testdox` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're on windows! These characters before each line works in unix environments and their usage is colorizing terminal output. So I suggest you to use git bash on windows.

Comment: git bash didnt work, but a separate thread led me to here
http://jasonkarns.com/blog/2012/04/03/ansi-color-in-windows-shells/

Answer (score 0):

Git Bash unfortunately didn't work for my situation, I stumbled upon this thread, hope it will help others

[(Windows 10) GitBash not formatting colors - can't find configuration settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652866/windows-10-gitbash-not-formatting-colors-cant-find-configuration-settings)

it works quite well now
[image]