# Detect Exact Windows 10 Version to Echo Colored Text in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

Based on this post for changing the output color of command prompt text in Windows 10, I'm looking for the best way to detect the OS version in a batch file IF statement.

[How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line/38617204#38617204)

From my understanding, colorized text was added in Windows 10 Threshold 2 November 18, 2015 (10.0.10586.11)

In Windows 10 version history, up until the Version 1607 (Anniversary Update), there was a major.minor.build.revision numbering scheme so I want the detection to be very granular.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history

I found this post which compares major.minor.build to a user input, but can't wrap my head around what it's doing for my needs.

https://github.com/LogicDaemon/PersonalUseScripts/blob/c3346df9c7c0f57b584b5c0238b8e8b76096c42c/cmd/superuser%20q%20891742/CheckWinVer.cmd

So based on that information, I'm trying to compare the detected version of windows to 10.0.10586.11 in a batch file.

If its greater than or equal to that version, colorize the text, if not use standard formatting.

This was my first attempt to colorize text in an IF statement.  Although this appeared to work in Windows 10, it didn't work in Windows 8.1 because string "10." is less than "6.3"

```
FOR /F "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') DO SET Version=%%i.%%j
IF "%Version%" GEQ "10.0" (echo [92mHere is my text in green.[0m) ELSE (echo Here is my text)
```

*Note the required escape characters are missing in the above sample*

Comment: Use PowerShell, where you can specify colors for `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare numeric values instead of strings (e.g. Windows 8.1 returns `603`):

```
FOR /F "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') DO SET /A _Version=%%i*100+%%j
IF %_Version% GEQ 1000 (echo [92mHere is my text in green.[0m) ELSE (echo Here is my text)
```

**Edit**. Instead of wikipedia, I'd use a primary source [Windows 10 release information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on Microsoft’s TechNet site.

```
FOR /F "tokens=4-7 delims=[]. " %%i in ('ver') DO (
  SET /A _MajorMinor = %%i * 100 + %%j
  set /A _Build      = %%k0 /10
  set /A _Revision   = %%l0 /10
)
set "_AE="        AE like Ansi Escape
IF %_MajorMinor% GEQ 1000 if %_Build% GTR 10586 ( set "_AE=Yes" ) else ( 
      if %_Build% EQU 10586 if %_Revision% GEQ 11 set "_AE=Yes" )
rem use the _AE flag
if defined _AE (echo [92mHere is my text in green.[0m) ELSE (echo Here is my text)
```

Used nested `IF`s (effective as of logical `AND`).

The `set /A _Revision = %%l0 /10` construct used to avoid `Missing operator` on Windows 8 where the 7th token `%%l` results to an empty string.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach to just get it working for Windows 8.1 but I want to get granular down to the sub-versioning numbers for unpatched Windows 10

Comment: Unless you can add a decimal point in there...  For 10.0.10586.11, would need tokens 4-7 and the possibility of the missing operator also.  Something like 10*100+0+10586+.11  How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Save yourself the pain and frustration and use PowerShell instead.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have no problem with PowerShell (pros >> cons) but the question **a)** is tagged *batch-file*, and  **b)** is not about *colouring* output.

Comment: @JosefZ Your example just needs delims=[.] I was getting a missing operator due to ] at the end.

Comment: @JosefZ is there a difference with []. vs [.] or was that a typo?  I'm a newbie with delimiters

Comment: @TechFA order of characters does not matter **excepting** default delimiters (<tab> and <space>) **if** used ( then, a space must be placed last i.e. right before closing `"` double quote) Read more under _Delims_ and _Splitting a string that includes spaces_ headers in https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html.