# Batch File - Colored text only works outside of if

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with this code:

```sh
for %%n in (%listPath%) do (        
    echo Starting Build
    echo.
    devenv %%n /build Debug
        
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        echo [101;93m ERROR: Error Build Project: %%n [0m
        pause > nul
        exit /b
    )
)
```

Why does the line `echo [101;93m ERROR: Error Build Project: %%n [0m` work only outside the `if` statement? I want to display a red error inside the `if`.

Comment: That line will not color the text independent of the position, the escape character in front of the sequence is missing

Comment: the esc tag is in the code, it's stackoverflow that deleted it for me.

Comment: the code works if I put it out of the if.

Comment: It's better to use a variable containing an escape character, like `for /F "delims=#" %%a in ('prompt #$E# ^& for %%a in ^(1^) do rem') do set "ESC=%%a"
` and use it `echo %ESC%[101;93m ERROR: %ESC[m`

Comment: I suppose your problem is elsewhere. Try a minimal example. First echo it outside the `IF` then inside `IF` but no other code. Probably one of your called programs like `devenv` *destroys* the escape handling

Comment: @jeb I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work

Comment: @jeb yeah, devenv destroys the escape handling. How can i fix it? thanks

Comment: You could check if it works with `devenv %%n /build Debug > NUL`. I read something about this problem before, but can't remember where, but probably it was a post/discovery from [@dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham)

Comment: yeah, it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example works as expected

```
@echo off

for /F "delims=#" %%a in ('prompt #$E# ^& for %%a in ^(1^) do rem') do set "ESC=%%a"

echo %ESC%[101;93m Test #1 %ESC%[0m
if 1==1 (
    echo %ESC%[42m Test #2 %ESC%[0m
)
```

It also works with direct placement of escape characters.

---

From the comments:
The problem was caused by `devenv` and can be solved by redirecting the output.

```
devenv %%n /build Debug > NUL
```

Description of the underlying problem:
[SO: ANSI color Set Graphics Rendition breaking mid-batch and working after it proceeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894515/ansi-color-set-graphics-rendition-breaking-mid-batch-and-working-after-it-procee)

Comment: how can i make it work with devenv?