# Can sqlcmd be configured support ANSI escape sequences (for coloring PRINT output)

Tags: sqlcmd

I am running a .sql script through sqlcmd in a cmd shell and would like the script to emit my PRINT output in color.

[How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line) demonstrates how the Windows 10 CMD supports ANSI escape sequences.

I am guessing sqlcmd runs it's own cmd shell because the colors don't appear.

```
sqlcmd -S (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
> print 'NOTE: my message'
> go
NOTE: my message  <--- Appears white on black.
```

In the next print there is ^[.
^[ is how the command shell renders a literal escape character.
The literal escape is entered from the keyboard using key combination Alt-Keypad 027.

```
> print '^[92mNOTE: my message ^[0m'
> go
□92mNOTE: my message□0m <--- Would like this to appear bright green on black
```

The sqlcmd shell is not supporting ANSI escape sequences.  The escape character is output as a box (□) glyph and 92m sequence for bright green does not get interpreted.

Can the sqlcmd shell be configured to support the ANSI escape sequences?

I am using Windows 10 and SQLExpress 2016.

```
>sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 11.0.2100.60 NT x64
Copyright (c) 2012 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closer read of [sqlcmd utility documentation][1] under "Miscellaneous Commands" shows the feature

- [:] !!< command> Executes operating system commands.

So the ECHO command can be issued with ANSI escape sequences to get coloring

```
:!!ECHO <alt-027>[1;32mThis is bright green.<alt-027>[0m This is not.
```