# How to change the background colour of highlighted text on windows cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

How to change the background colour of highlighted text on windows cmd?

The background colour changes to white however highlighted text background still seems to show as black even though I have changed all the background colours to white.

For example if there is a failure, it will show the exception text background as black instead of white.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is this even possible?

Comment: Hi Dominique, changing of the highlighted text to white instead of black?

Comment: How did you get this text to be black? I believe you've selected it, I don't know if it's possible to change the colour of text in the command prompt, based on the content of the text you're displaying.

Comment: Highlighting just swaps foreground and background colors. You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line/38617204#38617204)