# Printing text in different colours in the Windows CMD

Tags: c++, console-application, windows-console

I am planning to make a console game in C++, kind of like Dwarf Fortress (although I don't know if it was coded in C++), but I have encountered a big problem.

I want to display different things in different colours on the screen at once. I also need to change something that has already been printed (so that I don't have to re-print everything and make the screen flash annoyingly, especially that I will want to make changes every second or so) and I found a way to do that with WriteConsoleOutput() and although I don't know yet exactly how to use it, I'll be reading into it soon.

As for the colours, I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line) about some ANSI Escape things, but it
a) doesn't work, even when copying the linked code from github
b) I don't know if it'll work with attempts to over-write the console in specific places with WriteConsoleOutput()

So my request is: could someone please ELI5 to me what am I supposed to do and why, as well as present with a viable solution to this combination of two problems so that I can replicate something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_Fortress#/media/File:Dwarf_Fortress_world_generation.png), with the possibilty of changing what the characters show.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The probably easiest way is to use a library like ncurses.

Comment: There is also `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`.