# Trying to use RGB colors in windows console

Tags: console, rgb

I'm fairly new to programming and I try to use colors in the console but it doesn't have many option so I would like to change the 16 base colors so I get personalised ones. I found this code but it doesn't really work (the colors dont changes).

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info;
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);

info.ColorTable[0] = RGB(0,0,0);
...
info.ColorTable[3] = RGB(135, 206, 235);
...
info.ColorTable[15] = RGB (25,25,25);

SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);`
```

Comment: P.S. first time using a forum so I probably did something wrong in the post already

Comment: Only a little. Always prefix every line of code with at least 4 spaces, or surround it with 3 backticks in a row, on their own line. This is a backtick: `

Answer (score 1):

I always thought to change the console colors on a word by word basis you had to print out certain escape sequences of characters. Was quite surprised to learn from [How to echo with different colors in the Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line) that it's only this year or so that this has become a thing in the native command prompt. Maybe I'm thinking of the Commodore Amiga when I thought this had been possible for decades in DOS prompts

The accepted answer in the above linked question links to a github project for changing the colors; perhaps you can incorporate this into your app in some way to allow customizing of the colors

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`, you have to first set cbSize of `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX`.
The simplest way is something like that:

```
//Example of changing palette
int main()
{
    HANDLE outH = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //It doesn't make sense to everytime call GetStdHandle
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX oldOne, newBuff; 
    oldOne.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &oldOne);
    oldOne.srWindow.Bottom++; //After getting current buffer window usually makes smaller
    newBuff = oldOne; //Copy your current to new

    /* Edit your new buffer */

    //Set your dreamed buffer
    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &newBuff);

    /* Do something */

    //restore to defaults
    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(outH, &oldOne);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, all that I changed is `oldOne.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX)`. It's important because in another way `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` will failure. For more information go [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfoex). Pay attention that after changing your console palette, you will never restore it, so better add some lines to your code to save your previous one.