How to change text color for single word in the same line
Basically want to change a single word in the middle of text in cmd heres a short code example of what I want to do
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

color 0a
title App
cls

:welcome_page
cls
echo Welcome to App 
call :colorEcho 0C "Menu in red" :colorEcho 0B "and this text in a different color" :colorEcho 0C "back to red"
echo.
pause
exit

:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i


https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250760/388389 - check this answer.

I am pretty sure that I tried this already, but now it's working.
call :colorEcho 0C "Menu"&call :colorEcho 0B "and this text in a different color"&call :colorEcho 0C "back to red"
echo(
call :colorEcho 0a "test"
echo(
pause

