# How can I mask/hide password entry in WinPE using batch or vbscript?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, vbscript, passwords, winpe

I need password entry to not be displayed while typing. It can either stay blank or use * characters. It can be in either batch or vbscript and it will only be used while booted into WinPE. In older versions, we used this vbscript

```
CreateObject("ScriptPW.Password")
```

However, I'm finding this is no longer available with Windows 7. I read it's because of a no longer supported file scriptpw.dll. This needs to be done without external files or 3rd party executables.

Thanks!

Comment: See the end section of the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file

Comment: You can not register dll files in WinPE. I came across that page before I posted and it's just not possible.

Comment: I've come up with a potential solutions involving HTA. I can mask a password with it, but I need to use these variables outside of the HTA file. All of the scripts are already written in batch and vbs, so converting everything to HTA just for this one feature is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation.  I've created an x86 WinPE boot disk for recovering data from encrypted hard drives where the OS is FUBAR'ed.  I used Windows ADK 8.1.

Sadly, I discovered that **net use** is broken in WinPE.  When you want to map a share folder, you have to enter your password in the command string; it won't prompt you for it & mask the password.  Seeing as I am in the security organization, instructing folks to type their password in a visible command string would not go over very well...

I was able to include scriptpw.dll in my custom boot disk, and running regsvr32 to register it *seemed* to work, however, when I run the vbscript I had written for mapping drives, when it gets to the section of the code where I call ScriptPW.Password.GetPassword() to prompt for the user's password, it still shows the typed characters.  The script works like a charm on any full version of x86 Windows.