# Batch File Username and Password Save

Tags: batch-file

I have been playing around with batch files and made a log in i just need it to save the username and password in a .txt. I have tried multiple things but nothing is working.

Comment: so what does this have to do with C++?

Comment: @JonTrauntvein I think when you ask a question, it suggests `c++`.  Maybe if you don't tag your question, it automatically tags it `c++` for you.

Comment: How about you show some of the multiple things you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the password being in plain text -

```
set /p username="Enter username: "
set /p password="Enter password: "
echo %username% >credentials.txt
echo %password%>>credentials.txt
cls
```

If you would like to mask the input when the user enters their password have a look at some of the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file) - I suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file/20343074#20343074) answer (my answer), because it's a pretty robust method, for which you don't have to have external scripts - providing Powershell is installed.