# batch file to replace the input with * without external file

Tags: file, batch-file, input, replace

i need batch file to mask the input with * without external file and i need the code to ((((be fast in write letters))))) and does not Calculates the distance with *

((((if there is code extract the external file from the batch file which make the external file make password with * and fast to write password add comment to see the code ))))

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
 @echo off
 set char=*
 set /p variable=Enter your password:
 set char=%variable%
 echo %char%
 pause
```

Comment: Two possible duplicates: **1** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893172/how-can-i-mask-input-by-using-batch-file-without-extra-file/ **2** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942383/batch-file-to-mask-input-with-without-an-external-file

Answer (score 2):

This is a "cleanup" of the code you get in your previous question. If this is not fast enough for you, then you should consider not doing it in batch and use some aditional tool.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem Call the subroutine to get the password    
    call :getPassword password 

rem Echo what the function returns
    if defined password (
        echo You have typed [%password%]
    ) else (
        echo You have typed nothing
    )

rem End of the process    
    endlocal
    exit /b


rem Subroutine to get the password
:getPassword returnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "_password="

    rem We need a backspace to handle character removal
    for /f %%a in ('"prompt;$H&for %%b in (0) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

    rem Prompt the user 
    set /p "=password ?:" <nul 

:keyLoop
    rem retrieve a keypress
    set "key="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /l /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>nul') do if not defined key set "key=%%a"
    set "key=%key:~-1%"

    rem handle the keypress 
    rem     if No keypress (enter), then exit
    rem     if backspace, remove character from password and console
    rem     else add character to password and go ask for next one
    if defined key (
        if "%key%"=="%BS%" (
            if defined _password (
                set "_password=%_password:~0,-1%"
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set /p "=!BS! !BS!"<nul & endlocal
            )
        ) else (
            set "_password=%_password%%key%"
            set /p "=*"<nul
        )
        goto :keyLoop
    )
    echo(
    rem return password to caller
    if defined _password ( set "exitCode=0" ) else ( set "exitCode=1" )
    endlocal & set "%~1=%_password%" & exit /b %exitCode%
```