# batch file to mask input with * without an external file

Tags: file, batch-file, input, mask

i need batch file to mask the input with * without external file and i need the code to be fast to write letters

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
     @echo off
     set char=*
     set /p variable=Enter your password:
     set char=%variable%
     echo %char%
     pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mask an input text in a bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it using Powershell in a batch file

```
@echo off
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
echo %password%
```

Powershell is installed by default on all newer OS's so it's a good compromise. If you have to support XP machines, you can do something similar with VBScript.

Comment: WHEN I click in the left mouse and move the mouse it will show for my white thing i dont know how to explain it to you

Comment: Is the "for loop" actually the only way to eval that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There is a way in pure batch, with misusing of `xcopy` and `prompt` command we can do it

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call:show "Enter your passwordÿ" "0a"
call:hidePass
set /p password=<_tmp&del _tmp&echo/
echo/%password%
pause>nul
exit
:hidePass
    set "str="
    set "chars="
:writing
    set "key="
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`xcopy /L /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>NUL`) do (
        if not defined key set "key=%%L"
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "key=!key:~-1!"
    if "%key%" == "" (echo/!str!>_tmp&exit/b)
    call:show "-" "0c"
    set "str=!str!!key!"
    goto :writing
:show
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
        set "DEL=%%a"
    )
    call :ColorText %~2 "%~1"
    exit/b
:ColorText
    <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
    findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
    del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
    exit/b
```

The only problem is you can not use * as mask, in this case I'm using `-`

Comment: I stand corrected. that's some very interesting code. I tried with `*` just to see what it would do ;) ctrl-c ctrl-c quick!

Comment: if you edit the - to be * it will be better and there disadvantage is the space show * in the box idont want the space to show in box * can you edit these things ?

Comment: and when i write the password i feel it is slow to write the letters can you give another code to type letters faster ?