# Batch file login

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch file (login.cmd) that calls login variables from a signup file (signup.cmd); but I don't know exactly how to do it.

**signup.cmd**

```
::Copyright 2014 Krii.
@echo off
color f0
title Sign Up
echo Welcome,
set /p usern=Choose Username: 
set /p passwd=Choose Password: 
set /p bd=BD mm/dd/yyyy: 
set /p email=Email: 
echo USER >> docs/users.txt
echo ==== >> docs/users.txt
echo Username=%usern% >> docs/users.txt
echo Password=%passwd% >> docs/users.txt
echo BD=%bd% >> docs/users.txt
echo Email=%email% >> docs/users.txt
cls
echo Thank You.
echo.
echo Press any key to Login. . .
pause >nul
start login.bat
exit
```

**login.cmd**

```
::Copyright 2014 Krii.
@echo off
color f0
title Login
echo Please login to continue.
set /p usern=Username:
set /p passwd=Password:
```

=> => =>

```
if %usern%==%usern% in signup.cmd && %passwd%==%passwd% in signup.cmd goto authGood
goto authBad
```

=> => =>

There is an error in line 7 and 8 in login.cmd.
I can't figure out what to do.

Please Help
Thanks.

Comment: @aphoria  " 'in' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". But it is a command.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file/20343074#20343074) if you want to mask the password input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is not a command, but part of the syntax of the `for`command.

`IF` has no `in`

you can simply import the variables from your file:

```
cd docs
for /f "delims=" %%i in (users.txt) do set %%i
```

then get the new variables:

```
set /p usern=Username:
set /p passwd=Password:
```

and compare the old variables to the new variables:

```
if %usern%==%Username% if %paswd%==%Password% goto authGood
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Says "------- 'DOCS/USERS.TXT' is not defined."

Comment: do you have a space in `"delims= "`? If yes, remove it.

Comment: ah - no. I think, you have `"delims=="`

Comment: @Krii: nice edit. The `find "="` was there to process not all lines. (you had some lines in your example that will lead to errors or may unintended delete variables). The `"` were there to prevent syntax errors, if a variable is emty.