# Hide keyboard input in a batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a command line code to perform some operations which require a password from the user.I am reading the password from cmd using set/p "pass=>" .
But while using this the password being typed is displayed. I do not want it to be displayed on the cmd window. what modification should i make?

Comment: Can you edit to add details about what (if anything) you do want displayed?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24396149/388389

Comment: Am using this for locking the folder in windows using cmd. For which I found the code in Google. But the password entered in that is displayed as it is.I want nothing to be displayed when I type the password.

Comment: If npocmaka's password masking suggestion is not going to work for you, then you could forego storing the password in a variable and instead have the script relaunch itself using `runas`.  That would prompt for a password and remain silent during user entry, if I recall correctly.  And maybe under the `runas` context, additional authentication won't be needed.

Comment: Shameless self-plug: 5 years ago, I've written [a tiny C# Console application that lets you read-in text input from the user in a batch file without echoing it back to the console](http://blog.magerquark.de/scriptpw-dll-on-windows-2008-and-windows-7-scriptpw-password/). Maybe you could use this application in your batch file, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think CMD does not work in this way. i am guessing you have some sort of a **if statement** on the inside that will start to run the rest of the program if your input is right. batch files is just a way to get your daily operations faster :)

`cls`after "password" typed will prevent people from seeing the password after it was entered.

or maybe this post can help you:
[Can I mask an input text in a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file?lq=1)