# How to mask the HSQL password

Tags: java, windows, hsqldb

I have created a batch file to connect to HSQL database, here when we entered the password to connect to database it appears as a clear text

we cannot specify a non-empty password as an argument. You will be prompted for a password as part of the login process.but it appears that while password is being entered, it appears as clear text and as typed!
I want to mask this password, it should appear as ***.

My batch file:

```
java -jar sqltool.jar --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8888/XX,user=DDD
```

Comment: When you say "DOS", do you mean a Windows command prompt (i.e. `cmd.exe`)?

Comment: Yes, I have created batch file and executed on command propt

Comment: OK. Have look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file) question, more specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343074/1529709).

Comment: Thanks for ur input, I have tried using the details given in the page but sqltool.jar have inbult functionality to prompt for the password when we not provide. Again, when this application is deployed on linux and from there i will point to my bat file to connect to database.. I think powershell will not execute from bash consol... Can u suggest some other way..Thanks in advance

Comment: @java wouldn't that be a problem with your sqltool.jar and not a batch file problem.  That seems like a function of your java program.  It is definitely not a batch file problem.

Comment: @Squashman is right. Skimming though the [docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html), you could provide it in a `sqltool.rc` file, albeit in plain-text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides the [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class for basic terminal IO, including not displaying passwords the user inputs via [`readPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--):

> Reads a password or passphrase from the console with echoing disabled

This is not secure in any way - the password is still entered as cleartext - but if your intent is simply to avoid the password being seen on the screen as it's entered, this is the correct mechanism.

Comment: |Thanks, This is usefull