# What is the fastest color function in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console

I recently experimented with using multiple colors in one cmd window. Every color function that I find, (for example this one: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41155 ) are very slow, and it takes for ever to load a color map.

If you ask, by color map I mean this piece of code:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f) do (
    for %%b in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f) do (
        call :color %%a%%b %%a%%b
        if %%a%%b==1f call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==3f call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==5f call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==7f call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==9f call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==bf call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==df call :color \n
        if %%a%%b==ff call :color \n
    )
)

:color - some color function
```

With every color function in batch this code runs very slow. I suppose it is because of creating files in %Temp% directory.

Is there a color function in batch that works almost immediately if there are a lot of colors used at once? External programs or powershell counts too!

Comment: Did you notice in that link you posted that he also created a binary executable called out.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those pure batch solutions are slow. Try cecho: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files

It is very fast and displays output immediately even when there are hundreds of colors displayed in the same time.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect someone to answer so fast! I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10, as ANSI escape color sequences was implemented, you can try that:

```
@echo off

setlocal
call :setESC

cls
echo %ESC%[101;93m STYLES %ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[0m %ESC%[0mReset%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[1m %ESC%[1mBold%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[4m %ESC%[4mUnderline%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m %ESC%[7mInverse%ESC%[0m
echo.
echo %ESC%[101;93m NORMAL FOREGROUND COLORS %ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[30m %ESC%[30mBlack%ESC%[0m (black)
echo ^<ESC^>[31m %ESC%[31mRed%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[32m %ESC%[32mGreen%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[33m %ESC%[33mYellow%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[34m %ESC%[34mBlue%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[35m %ESC%[35mMagenta%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[36m %ESC%[36mCyan%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[37m %ESC%[37mWhite%ESC%[0m
echo.
echo %ESC%[101;93m NORMAL BACKGROUND COLORS %ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[40m %ESC%[40mBlack%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[41m %ESC%[41mRed%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[42m %ESC%[42mGreen%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[43m %ESC%[43mYellow%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[44m %ESC%[44mBlue%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[45m %ESC%[45mMagenta%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[46m %ESC%[46mCyan%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[47m %ESC%[47mWhite%ESC%[0m (white)
echo.
echo %ESC%[101;93m STRONG FOREGROUND COLORS %ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[90m %ESC%[90mWhite%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[91m %ESC%[91mRed%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[92m %ESC%[92mGreen%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[93m %ESC%[93mYellow%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[94m %ESC%[94mBlue%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[95m %ESC%[95mMagenta%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[96m %ESC%[96mCyan%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[97m %ESC%[97mWhite%ESC%[0m
echo.
echo %ESC%[101;93m STRONG BACKGROUND COLORS %ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[100m %ESC%[100mBlack%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[101m %ESC%[101mRed%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[102m %ESC%[102mGreen%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[103m %ESC%[103mYellow%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[104m %ESC%[104mBlue%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[105m %ESC%[105mMagenta%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[106m %ESC%[106mCyan%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[107m %ESC%[107mWhite%ESC%[0m
echo.
echo %ESC%[101;93m COMBINATIONS %ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m                     %ESC%[31mred foreground color%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m                      %ESC%[7minverse foreground ^<-^> background%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7;31m                   %ESC%[7;31minverse red foreground color%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m and nested ^<ESC^>[31m %ESC%[7mbefore %ESC%[31mnested%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m and nested ^<ESC^>[7m %ESC%[31mbefore %ESC%[7mnested%ESC%[0m

:setESC
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set ESC=%%b
  exit /B 0
)
exit /B 0
```

This has been written by

[Michele Locati](https://github.com/mlocati)

This is really fast, no PowerShell nor FindStr slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a powershell solution, `Write-Host` supports console colors:

```
Clear-Host
Write-Host "######" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host '" ' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host '21' -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline
Write-Host ' !' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host '######' -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at that too :)