# Batch file: Password Stars/Circles

Tags: batch-file, passwords

Like you already know, websites have certain special chars for passwords, like stars and circles.

Could this be possible in a batch file, on the following one:?

If this is not possible, if you type it in, could you just see nothing?

```
set pass=
set /p pass=Enter your password: 
if {%pass%}=={} goto :begin
set authenticated=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (pass.txt) do (
    if {%%a}=={%pass%} set authenticated=true
)
if not defined authenticated (echo Invalid password & goto :begin)
```

But i need to get this in it:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript /nologo GetPwd.vbs')
```

HOW!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the Windows batch equivalent for HTML's input type="password"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286871/what-would-be-the-windows-batch-equivalent-for-htmls-input-typepassword)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mask an input text in a bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is my **editenv** command-line tool:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv/

```
editenv --maskinput --prompt "Password: " PWD
```

Note that this doesn't provide security, as (in this example) the content of the `PWD` environment variable is clear-text. Still, it does provide input masking in cases where this might be useful.

---

[Old obsolete answer]

Another alternative is my EditV32 (x86) or EditV64 (x64) command-line tools. For example:

editv32 -m -p "Password: " PWD

-m means "masked input" and -p is the prompt. The user's input is stored in the PWD environment variable. You can get it here:

http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html

Comment: Thanks, this is a very easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly.  You would have to write a password entry programme in something else and then run it from your batch file to capture the password.

Comment: and... if you type it in, but just see nothing?

Comment: I don't see how it COULD be possible given the lack of control batch files give you over processing the standard input stream.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways of accomplishing this are given here: [Can I mask an input text in a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file).  Also, maybe someone marks this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

[How to create a masked input to a batch file](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-create-a-masked-input-to-a-batch-file/) - does that help ? It appears to vary somewhat depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Got it done:

Batch file:

```
@echo off
<nul: set /p passwd=Password: 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript /nologo GetPwd.vbs') do set passwd=%%i
```

GetPwd.vbs:

```
Set oScriptPW = CreateObject("ScriptPW.Password")
strPassword = oScriptPW.GetPassword()
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine strPassword
```

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. The `ScriptPW.Password` component does not exist past Windows XP.