# log in batch program

Tags: batch-file

i have been formulating and doing a batch program that enables the user to enter his password,just like that, and i seem to arrive at nothingness, can anybody show me how to create a batch program that enables the user to enter his password?and run a specific program when log in is successfull, by the way, i am using windows xp sp2

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the Windows batch equivalent for HTML's input type="password"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286871/what-would-be-the-windows-batch-equivalent-for-htmls-input-typepassword)

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p "PASSWORD=Enter your password: "
```

I use the quotes so I can show the trailing space in the batch file.  Otherwise it's not necessary; any trailing spaces will be echoed into the output.

`set /?` shows a number of ways of manipulating variables in `cmd.exe`

Comment: I guess this only answers the first question.  For the second, I'm not sure how you would "log in" as another user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works for me...

```
@echo off

:loginPASS
set /p password=Password: 
if %password% == qwerty goto loginsuccessful
if %password% == %password% goto loginfailed

:loginfailed
echo Login failed, password was incorrect!
pause
cls
goto login

:loginsuccessful
echo LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!
cd <location of file (dont include its name) example: C: /Users/YOURUSERNAME/desktop>
<type in file name here>
```

if you want to make a username input too, then delete the loginPASS section make a new one called loginUSER and type in this:

```
:loginUSER
set /p username=Username
cls
if %username% == Admin goto AdminLogin
if %username% == Bob goto BobLogin
if %username% == %username% goto NoUsername
```

make a new section called NoUsername
    :NoUsername
    echo User not found, check your username again.
    pause
    cls
    goto loginUSER
this will tell the user if they entered the wrong username.
after that make a new section for 1 of the users and name appropriately.
in this case you will name it AdminLogin.

After that repeat loginPASS and make the password for the user.

The whole code should look something like this:

@echo off

```
:AdminLogin
set /p password=Password: 
if %password% == 158468 goto loginsuccessful
if %password% == %password% goto loginfailed

:loginfailedADMIN
echo Login failed, password was incorrect!
pause
cls
goto AdminLogin

:loginsuccessfulADMIN
echo LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!
cd <location of file (dont include its name) example: C: /Users/YOURUSERNAME/desktop>
<type in file name here>
pause
exit
```

You will want to make seperate login sections for each user.
Hope this helps!

P.S There might be other ways but this is what i use.