# Hide password with asterisk in lua

Tags: lua

I there a way to ask password in lua but hide with asterisks?

I'm asking about a console application

Comment: It seems lua doesn't have a low level character read function. Maybe use os.execute() to call a script? Although there are security implementations if you do this on a production unix host. Or add a c function to call getchar if you're into that level. read(1) returns a single char but echoes the character - if you're on unix you could fiddle with the stty mode

Comment: Lua can't have a low-level character read function because ANSI C doesn't have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Unix: use `os.execute("stty -echo raw")` to turn off echoing and enter raw mode (character-by-character input) and `os.execute("stty echo cooked")` to turn it on and exit raw mode when you are done.  In raw mode, you can get each character of the input using `io.stdin:read(1)` and echo your asterisk as you go (use `io.flush` to ensure the character appears straight away).  You will need to handle deletes and the end of line yourself.

For Windows, the situation is a bit trickier.  Look at [What would be the Windows batch equivalent for HTML's input type=“password”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286871/what-would-be-the-windows-batch-equivalent-for-htmls-input-type-password) for some approaches, the best of which seems to be a VB script.

#### Postscript

Thanks for lhf for pointing out that you need raw mode besides `-echo` on input and flush after each output asterisk to get the desired result: unless you have both, the asteriskes will not be echoed until the line is ended.

Comment: You need to use `os.execute("stty -echo raw")` so that `io.read(1)` works as intended and `io.flush()` after printing the asterisk with `io.write("*")`.

Answer (score 2):

This code uses platform-specific features and works both on Linux and 32-bit Windows.
Compatible with Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2

```
local console

local function enter_password(prompt_message, asterisk_char, max_length)
   -- returns password string
   -- "Enter" key finishes the password
   -- "Backspace" key undoes last entered character
   if not console then
      if (os.getenv'os' or ''):lower():find'windows' then
         ------------------ Windows ------------------
         local shift = 10
         -- Create executable file which returns (getch()+shift) as exit code
         local getch_filespec = 'getch.com'
         -- mov AH,8
         -- int 21h
         -- add AL,shift
         -- mov AH,4Ch
         -- int 21h
         local file = assert(io.open(getch_filespec, 'wb'))
         file:write(string.char(0xB4,8,0xCD,0x21,4,shift,0xB4,0x4C,0xCD,0x21))
         file:close()
         console = {
            wait_key = function()
               local code_Lua51, _, code_Lua52 = os.execute(getch_filespec)
               local code = (code_Lua52 or code_Lua51) - shift
               assert(code >= 0, getch_filespec..' execution failed')
               return string.char(code)
            end,
            on_start = function() end,
            on_finish = function() end,
            backspace_key = '\b'
         }
         -------------------------------------------
      else
         ------------------ Linux ------------------
         console = {
            wait_key = function()
               return io.read(1)
            end,
            on_start = function()
               os.execute'stty -echo raw'
            end,
            on_finish = function()
               os.execute'stty sane'
            end,
            backspace_key = '\127'
         }
         -------------------------------------------
      end
   end
   io.write(prompt_message or '')
   io.flush()
   local pwd = ''
   console.on_start()
   repeat
      local c = console.wait_key()
      if c == console.backspace_key then
         if #pwd > 0 then
            io.write'\b \b'
            pwd = pwd:sub(1, -2)
         end
      elseif c ~= '\r' and #pwd < (max_length or 32) then
         io.write(asterisk_char or '*')
         pwd = pwd..c
      end
      io.flush()
   until c == '\r'
   console.on_finish()
   io.write'\n'
   io.flush()
   return pwd
end

-- Usage example
local pwd = enter_password'Enter password: '
print('You entered: '..pwd:gsub('%c','?'))
print(pwd:byte(1,-1))
```

Comment: I haven't tested it to be 100% sure, but the really clever trick of creating a COM file to do the raw character read in Windows will only work on 32-bit versions. COM files are legacy DOS 16-bit programs, and 64-bit editions of Windows do not support the 16-bit DOS emulation system. Otherwise, this is a clever solution overall.

Comment: @RBerteig - Do you have 64-bit Windows at your disposal?  I don't have such one at the moment.  Could you please test my code?

Comment: On 64-bit Windows 7 Pro, attempting to run `getch.com` puts up the error message "The program or feature....cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available."

Comment: The actual call to `os.execute"getch.com"` returns 1 as the first result in Lua 5.1, and a version of the same error message that also appears in a pop-up window appears on stderr. You could improve your loop by breaking on any control character and not just CR.... that would be friendlier if getch fails.

Comment: @RBerteig - Thank you very much for testing.  Control characters are permitted intentionally.  Password is not required to consist of only printable characters.  Almost any key (arrow-up, Alt-F12, PageDn, Ctrl-Enter, ...) could be included in password.

Comment: @RBerteig - Yes, `getch` errors are not handled properly - code would loop forever.  What action should be done if `getch` fails?  There is no option "refuse to enter password" provided.

Comment: If getch fails due to some system constraint (permissions, support for running it all as on 64-bit, or other causes) then `enter_password()` needs to call `error()` or visibly fail. The exit code of 1 seems to be what 64-bit win7 used, but I don't know that is documented or required. I don't have good answers here, just the general prescription that an endless loop where Ctrl+C can't be used because the system puts up a dialog box on every iteration is not ideal. A way out is to make getch be a 32-bit EXE file. You could use Alien or FFI to access the Console API directly as another approach.

Comment: @RBerteig - Yes, it would be wise to consider exit code == 1 as error.  Now `Ctrl-A` and `Alt-Esc` key combinations are unavailable inside password as their getch() codes contain byte == 1.

Comment: @RBerteig - Key code could be biased by 10 inside `getch.com`, so that any exit code 0..9 would imply error.  `Ctrl-A` and `Alt-Esc` are possible again.

Comment: The shift is a good approach for this bit of cleverness. On my 64-bit system it now fails noisily on the first character and doesn't require heroic measures to kill. :-)  64-bit windows is simply going to require a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Bug in code, for at least linux implementation.  Need to add 'and c ~= nil`:
elseif c ~= '\r' and #pwd < (max_length or 32) and c ~= nil then