# Password input function in Lua

Tags: passwords, lua, masking

How to make CLI password masking in Lua? E.g. when I write password it changes into asterisk or nothing is shown at all? I need platform-independent solution as my script will be used in Java application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide password with asterisk in lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787796/hide-password-with-asterisk-in-lua)

Comment: Are you running Lua inside the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain Lua, the answer is simple: you can't.

Since Lua is written in ANSI C you can not get characters from the command line without having to press enter. You can however make use of bindings to libraries like curses.lua which comes with [luaposix](https://github.com/rrthomas/luaposix).

Or if you can assume you'll have an ANSI VT, you can resort to a hack like this:

```
io.write("\027[s") -- save cursor position
l=io.read()
io.write('\027[u',('*'):rep(#l),"\n") -- rewind to where we were, and fill with the correct amount of stars
print("pst, I got", l, "but don't tell anyone!")
```

[More info about ANSI terminal control](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

But if it'll be used for a Java application, why not use Java for the password prompt. I guess their support and control of the cli would be better and cross-platform...