# Hide Input in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, hide, user-input

I was wondering how I would go about Hiding the input from a 'set /p' command in a batch file.

> set /p Password=What is your password?

We all know that inputting your password, you would be able to see it. How would I go 'bout hiding it ?

I tried conset.exe from [here.](http://ss64.net/westlake/nt/) And used:

> conset /PH Password=What is your password?

And i get "Conset: Error setting variable" :(

Another idea I had, was to change the colour of the console window. But how could I change the colour on the same line? So that you could see the question, but not see the answer?

Any ideas from the pros?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286871/what-would-be-the-windows-batch-equivalent-for-htmls-input-type-password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mask an input text in a bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably look at the answers here: [Can I mask an input text in a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file)

I think EditV32.exe and EditV64.exe are the best options you have (and since you were OK to use conset, which as far as I know does not come with Windows, I don't think you would oppose to using editv?)

http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html

Also: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/7d2d92a5-5d59-4954-bf3e-22eeb5cf0ee6/

Comment: Note that my `editv32`/`edit64` utilities have been superseded by my open-source [`editenv`](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv) utility.

Answer (score 11):

**1.Pure batch solution** that (ab)uses `XCOPY` command and its `/P /L` switches found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/f7mb_f99lYI) :

```
:: Hidden.cmd
::Tom Lavedas, 02/05/2013, 02/20/2013
::Carlos, 02/22/2013
::https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/f7mb_f99lYI


@Echo Off
:HInput
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FILE=%Temp%.\T"
Set "FILE=.\T"
Keys List >"%File%"
Set /P "=Hidden text ending with Ctrl-C?: " <Nul
Echo.
Set "HInput="
:HInput_
For /F "tokens=1* delims=?" %%A In (
 '"Xcopy /P /L "%FILE%" "%FILE%" 2>Nul"'
) Do (
  Set "Text=%%B"
  If Defined Text (
    Set "Char=!Text:~1,1!"
    Set "Intro=1"
    For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%Z in ("!Char!") Do Set "Intro=0"
    Rem If press Intro
    If 1 Equ !Intro! Goto :HInput#
    Set "HInput=!HInput!!Char!"
  )
)
Goto :HInput_
:HInput#
Echo(!HInput!
Goto :Eof
```

**2.1 [Another way based on replace command](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6382)**

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set /P "=Enter a Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput
Echo(Your input was:!Line!

Goto :Eof

:PasswordInput
::Author: Carlos Montiers Aguilera
::Last updated: 20150401. Created: 20150401.
::Set in variable Line a input password
For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'"Echo(|Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W"') Do Set "CR=%%#"
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt $H &For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%#"
Set "Line="
:_PasswordInput_Kbd
Set "CHR=" & For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W') Do Set "CHR=%%#"
If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&Goto :Eof
If !CHR!==!BS! (If Defined Line (Set /P "=!BS! !BS!" <Nul
Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
)
) Else (Set /P "=*" <Nul
If !CHR!==! (Set "Line=!Line!^!"
) Else Set "Line=!Line!!CHR!"
)
Goto :_PasswordInput_Kbd
```

**2.Password submitter that uses a HTA pop-up**
. [This is a hybrid .bat/jscript/mshta](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543) file and should be saved as a .bat:

```
<!-- :
:: PasswordSubmitter.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "pass=%%p"
)

echo your password is %pass%
exit /b
-->

<html>
<head><title>Password submitter</title></head>
<body>

    <script language='javascript' >
        function pipePass() {
            var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value;
            var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(fso.Write(pass));

        }
    </script>

    <input type='password' name='pass' size='15'></input>
    <hr>
    <button onclick='pipePass()'>Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**3.[A self-compiled .net hybrid](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5260)** .Again should be saved as `.bat` .In difference with other solutions it will create/compile a small .exe file that will be called (if you wish you can delete it). Also requires installed .net framework but that's rather not a problem:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)
if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('"%~n0.exe"') do (
    set "pass=%%p"
)
echo your password is !pass!

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%
*/

import System;

var pwd = "";
var key;
Console.Error.Write("Enter password: ");

        do {
           key = Console.ReadKey(true);

           if ( (key.KeyChar.ToString().charCodeAt(0)) >= 20 && (key.KeyChar.ToString().charCodeAt(0) <= 126) ) {
              pwd=pwd+(key.KeyChar.ToString());
              Console.Error.Write("*");
           }

           if ( key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pwd.Length > 0 ) {
               pwd=pwd.Remove(pwd.Length-1);
               Console.Error.Write("\b \b");
           }   
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.Error.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(pwd);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but xcopy.exe is not a "pure batch" solution. There is no pure batch solution as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

OK - so this answer comes 9 years later, but I guess better late than never...

I wrote the editv32/editv64 tool noted in the marked answer, but since then I wrote a slightly better tool:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv

The tool is free and open-source. Binary download is available from the `Releases` tab.

The `--maskinput` (`-m`) option lets you mask input (optionally with a user-defined character). Note that this feature is **NOT SECURE** (the variable value is still in memory and the environment in plain-text) -- it's for convenience only.

My most frequent use of this tool is to interactively edit the `Path` variable for the current process (it's turned out to be pretty handy for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

The simple code worked for me

```
:CVSPassword
echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>hide.com
set /P cvspassword=Please enter CVS Password:: <nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('hide.com') do set cvspassword=%%i
IF "%cvspassword%"=="" GOTO CVSPassword
echo cvspassword %cvspassword%
```

Comment: `hide.com`? Where is it? (and isn't it a 16 bit application, which won't run on 64 bit windows?)

Comment: Forgot to add echo command which will create a hide.com file which is used to hiding the password

Comment: @Stephan is correct, this does _not_ work on a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

To enter hidden numbers:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call:SecretInput "Password: " pw 4
call:SecretInput "Code: " c 5

echo.
echo Password is %pw%
echo Code is %c%
pause&exit

:SecretInput <String> <Var> <Len>
set %2=
set/a len=%3
for /l %%i in (1,1,99) do (
set/a l=%3-len
echo Press d to Delete
set/p .=%~1 <nul
for /l %%j in (1,1,!l!) do (
<nul set/p .=*)
choice /n /c:1234567890d>nul
set e=!errorlevel!&cls
if !e!==11 (
if "!%2!" neq "" (
set %2=!%2:~,-1!
set/a len+=1)
) else (
set/a e%%=10,len-=1
set %2=!%2!!e!)
if !len!==0 exit/b)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).