# Batch file input line featuring dots

Tags: batch-file, input

i am hoping there will be a solution to this,

I am wondering if some kind person can help me to create a input line which features dots as the field of entry...(every time a letter is typed, a dot is replaced)

Here's an example:

```
Action [cursor]· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
```

here is what I have so far, but I am stuck.

```js
@echo off
title Input with dots
set /p action = "·······················································"
if %action% == option1 goto print1
:print1
echo this works!
pause
exit
```

Comment: what have you tried? Post some code and we can perhaps help.

Comment: All ive got up to is just standard input, i really cant workout the rest...

Comment: so, at least post some of that.

Comment: posted.........

Comment: if you want to hide the input better check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396213/388389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the dots, move the cursor backward by outputting a bunch of backspace characters, then prompt the user.  To output a backspace character, you must capture a backspace to a variable.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // capture backspace character to a variable
rem // credit: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=22010#p22010
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

rem // cosmetic, non-functional prompt:
<NUL set /P "=Fill in the blank: .................................................."

rem // backspace 50 times (one for each dot)
for /L %%I in (1,1,50) do <NUL set /P "=%BS%"

rem // real prompt this time
set /P "response="

echo You entered "%response%".

pause
exit /b
```

---

Based on [@TripeHound's excellent idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331729/1683264) of using a carriage return to move the text cursor, here's an example of using a batch function to determine the number of dots to pad the line programmatically:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

call :prompt "Fill in the blank:" response
echo You entered "%response%"

call :prompt "This is a prompt of a different length:" response
echo You entered "%response%"

<NUL set /P "=Press any key to exit. " & pause >NUL & echo;
goto :EOF

:prompt <question> <return_var>
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "dots=................................................................................"
for /f "skip=4 tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('mode con') do if not defined cols (
    set /a cols = %%I - 4
)
call set "dots=%%dots:~-%cols%%%"
rem // credit: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/AUXP8XbRAJA
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do endlocal & set /P "%~2=%dots%%%a%~1 " & exit /b
```

Comment: thank you ever so much!, just quickly, how could i keep the dots after i've deleted the characters on top of them?

Comment: @LewisHughes Are you asking how to superimpose a character on top of another character so that both display at the same X,Y coordinate?  The cmd console doesn't allow that.

Comment: @rojo I think he means: if you use the backspace when filling in the answer, is there a way of (re)filling the empty space with dots (again).  `a .....` -> `ab ....` -> `a .....` instead of `a  ....`. I think not.

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks for the translation.  `:)`  @Lewis, while the execution thread is waiting for user input, there is no output, nor is there a way in the Batch language to listen for a backspace as far as I'm aware.  What you're asking has no easy solution.

Comment: okay, well i thank you for all your help, your a credit to this forum thank you @rojo

Comment: and you too @TripeHound

Answer (score 1):

A minor variant on [rojo's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331145/2096401). Instead of backspacing over the dots, this uses a carriage return (without line-feed) to output the prompt, the dots, CR and the prompt again:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/AUXP8XbRAJA
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "\r=%%a"

set "DOTS=.................................................."
set "PROMPT=Fill in the blank: "

set /p "response=%PROMPT%%DOTS%!\r!%PROMPT%"

echo You entered "%response%".
```

Although, as rojo notes, the use of `enabledelayedexpansion` may cause problems if you use exclamation marks elsewhere. One solution would be to put this code in a "subroutine" (where I additionally pass in the variable to contain the response and the prompt):

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :getString answer "Fill in the blank: "
echo You entered "%answer%".
goto :eof

:getString
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    REM From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/AUXP8XbRAJA
    for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "\r=%%a"

    set "DOTS=.................................................."
    set "PROMPT=%~2"

    set /p "response=%PROMPT%%DOTS%!\r!%PROMPT%"

    endlocal && set %1=%response%
    goto :eof
```

The last line (`endlocal && ...`) allows us to end locality (and delayed-expansion) while still using the value of an environment variable defined *within* that block).

(I was working on an alternative solution using the (now not standard, but easily available) `choice` command, to process the input character-by-character, but it doesn't look like it was going anywhere).

Comment: Delayed Expansion will mangle exclamation marks.  But I like the efficiency of the carriage return idea.

Comment: @rojo It appears delayed-expansion is necessary for the CR to work (`!\r!` works, `%\r%` does not).